# Overriding __cmp__, __eq__, and __hash__ for SQLAlchemy Declarative Base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to override `__cmp__`, `__eq__`, and `__hash__` so I can do set operations on a SQLAlchemy Declarative Base model. Will this cause any conflicts with the Declarative Base Implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. It'll work just fine.

Comment: Can you cite any SQLAlchemy documentation that suggests that this would be ok?

Comment: @DuneBug I can't see why it would be a problem. Sqlalchemy itself doesn't override those special methods for the declarative base.

Comment: If SQLAlchemy ever uses __eq__ like @ovidiu mentions, it could be an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, depending on the comparison function implementation.

You have to be careful when using `__eq__` or `__cmp__` for comparing with the `other` object, because SQLAlchemy may compare your object with some symbols such as `NEVER_SET` which don't have the same type. Take a look at this SQLAlchemy method:

```
def get_all_pending(self, state, dict_):
    if self.key in dict_:
        current = dict_[self.key]
        if current is not None:
            ret = [(instance_state(current), current)]
        else:
            ret = [(None, None)]

        if self.key in state.committed_state:
            original = state.committed_state[self.key]
            if original not in (NEVER_SET, PASSIVE_NO_RESULT, None) and \
                original is not current:

                ret.append((instance_state(original), original))
        return ret
    else:
        return []
```

The `original not in (NEVER_SET, PASSIVE_NO_RESULT, None)` line may raise an error if the comparison doesn't check for the equality of the types first, or for the existence of the fields that are used in the comparison

As a solution, you should take differing types into account.

Also avoid overriding `__cmp__` and use [rich comparison operators instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061283/lt-instead-of-cmp).

Comment: Good catch! This is important.