# TypeError: unorderable types: Card() < Card()

Tags: python, oop

I am tyring to learn Object oriented programming in python. I came across the book `thinkpython` by  `Allen B. Downey`.I am trying to run the following example `card.py`, but I am getting some error.

```
"""This module contains code from
Think Python by Allen B. Downey
http://thinkpython.com
Copyright 2012 Allen B. Downey
License: GNU GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
"""

import random


class Card(object):
    """Represents a standard playing card.
    Attributes:
      suit: integer 0-3
      rank: integer 1-13
    """

    suit_names = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    rank_names = [None, "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
              "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a human-readable string representation."""
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank],
                             Card.suit_names[self.suit])

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        """Compares this card to other, first by suit, then rank.
        Returns a positive number if this > other; negative if other > this;
        and 0 if they are equivalent.
        """
        t1 = self.suit, self.rank
        t2 = other.suit, other.rank
        return cmp(t1, t2)


class Deck(object):
    """Represents a deck of cards.
    Attributes:
      cards: list of Card objects.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def add_card(self, card):
        """Adds a card to the deck."""
        self.cards.append(card)

    def remove_card(self, card):
        """Removes a card from the deck."""
        self.cards.remove(card)

    def pop_card(self, i=-1):
        """Removes and returns a card from the deck.
        i: index of the card to pop; by default, pops the last card.
        """
        return self.cards.pop(i)

    def shuffle(self):
        """Shuffles the cards in this deck."""
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        """Sorts the cards in ascending order."""
        self.cards.sort()

    def move_cards(self, hand, num):
        """Moves the given number of cards from the deck into the Hand.
        hand: destination Hand object
        num: integer number of cards to move
        """
        for i in range(num):
            hand.add_card(self.pop_card())


class Hand(Deck):
    """Represents a hand of playing cards."""

    def __init__(self, label=''):
        self.cards = []
        self.label = label


def find_defining_class(obj, method_name):
    """Finds and returns the class object that will provide
    the definition of method_name (as a string) if it is
    invoked on obj.
    obj: any python object
    method_name: string method name
    """
    for ty in type(obj).mro():
        if method_name in ty.__dict__:
            return ty
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()

    hand = Hand()
    print(find_defining_class(hand, 'shuffle'))

    deck.move_cards(hand, 5)
    hand.sort()
    print(hand)
```

I am getting the following error, when I try to run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Cubic/playpen/python/concepts/OO_concepts/card.py", line 120, in <module>
    hand.sort()
  File "C:/Cubic/playpen/python/concepts/OO_concepts/card.py", line 80, in sort
    self.cards.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: Card() < Card()
<class '__main__.Deck'>
```

I am using python version `3.5.1`

Comment: There is no cmp function in python3

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: You can implement `__lt__` in your card class. That is the function used by the built-in sort. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152497/making-a-python-user-defined-class-sortable-hashable

Comment: What is the logic behind the suit comparison?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I see. I don't think there is inherent logic.I would go with `spades > clubs > hearts > diamond`

Comment: Then just remove cmp, implement lt with `return t1[0] < t2[0] or t2[1] < t2[1]` where t1 and t2 are your objects from cmp, if you just compared as tuples you would be comparing strings to ints which is invalid using python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - you mean `return t1[0] < t2[0] or t1[1] < t2[1]`

Comment: @liv2hak, yep, cannot edit my comment as 5mins are up

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - no problem.thanks for the explanation.