# How can I create a custom __hash__ and __eq__ for python class instances who have dynamic dicts

Tags: python, class, hash, set, equality

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert. If the solution is obvious to you, that's awesome! Hopefully it will be ovious to me too someday.

I have created a class Trigger() for triggering events based on one or more rules.
Each instance has a method to evaluate if the rules are currently met. 
For example, if there is only one rule, "Wednesday 0800-1400" and it is currently Wednesday between those times, then the trigger returns True.

Overlapping triggers are not allowed (see example below)

TriggerOne = {
    day: "Monday",
    start: "08:00",
    end: "14:00"
}

TriggerTwo = {
    day: "Monday",
    start: "12:00",
    end:"16:00"
}

To test overlapping triggers I implemented a self.**eq**() that returns True if time frames or other rules overlap between triggers, and False if the rule(s) do not overlap.

**HELP!**
I started writing a custom class to manage the triggers, but I was hoping there might be a way to make my trigger instances hashable based on their rules so that I can add them to a set()

I read this question, for which an answer states that equivalent instances should hash to the same thing:
[Making a python user-defined class sortable, hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152497/making-a-python-user-defined-class-sortable-hashable)

How could I (if it's possible) go about writing a self.**hash**() that could accomplish this?

I  really appreciate constructive feedback and ideas

Comment: Overlapping is not equality, or even an equivalence relation. A set is not the tool for the job.

Comment: Using a stdlib set is not a good way to go about this. Recommend to write your own class.