# Custom Python list sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was refactoring some old code of mine and came across of this:

```
alist.sort(cmp_items)

def cmp_items(a, b):
    if a.foo > b.foo:
        return 1
    elif a.foo == b.foo:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

The code works (and I wrote it some 3 years ago!) but I cannot find this thing documented anywhere in the Python docs and everybody uses `sorted()` to implement custom sorting. Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: `sorted()` and `sort()` offer custom sorting in much the same way, modulo the difference in calling convention.

Comment: Indeed, what happens is that using a `key` parameter is preferred over passing a  `cmp` function. (The later is not even implemented in Python 3)

Comment: It's kind of ambiguous, depends on what the items in the list were; your code requires that they have an attribute `foo`, otherwise it blows up. Better to define a custom `__lt__()` method for your class, then `sorted()` and `list.sort()` will work out-of-the-box. (Btw, objects no longer need to define `__cmp__()`, just `__lt__()` . [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061283/lt-instead-of-cmp())

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

> The sort() method takes optional arguments for controlling the
>   comparisons.
>
> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list
>   items) which should  return a negative, zero or positive number
>   depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than,
>   equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y:
>   cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

Comment: Thanks miles82 I was checking here and couldn't see it in the method signature http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I don't see the same text on the page you linked to. Did the documentation change. Besides, when I try to use `cmp`, I get `TypeError: 'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. What is going on here?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye sort() doesn't have a cmp argument in Python 3. This is an old answer when the docs link was for Python 2. You can find the old docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) or read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter). If you're using Python 3, use the [key argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) instead.

Comment: And what if you actually want to provide a comparison function? I want to treat numbers in a string (of any length, picked out greedily) as symbols, equivalently to how individual characters are otherwise treated. I know how to achieve that trivially if I may provide a comparison function, but not if I must provide a key function. Why was this changed?

Comment: I guess it can still be achieved if each number contained in the string is encoded using an encoding that orders the numbers lexicographically, such as [Levenshtein coding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_coding). But I consider this more as a workaround to the fact that `sort` doesn’t take a comparison function as argument in Python 3, and not as something that I *actually* would like to do.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye you can use [functools.cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to transform an old-style comparison function to a key function.

Comment: @miles82 Thanks!

Comment: Need sample code to be accepted in my view.

Answer (score 146):

As a side note, here is a better alternative to implement the same sorting:

```
alist.sort(key=lambda x: x.foo)
```

Or alternatively:

```
import operator
alist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('foo'))
```

Check out the [Sorting How To](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/), it is very useful.

Comment: TIL about operator, very useful.

Answer (score 33):

Just like this example. You want sort this list.

```
[('c', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

output:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

you should sort the tuples by the second item, then the first:

```
def letter_cmp(a, b):
    if a[1] > b[1]:
        return -1
    elif a[1] == b[1]:
        if a[0] > b[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

Then convert it to a key function:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
letter_cmp_key = cmp_to_key(letter_cmp))
```

Now you can use your custom sort order:

```
[('c', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)].sort(key=letter_cmp_key)
```

Comment: How does it know what list to sort?

Comment: @CameronMonks yourList.sort(letter_cmp)

Answer (score 21):

This does not work in Python 3.

You can use functools cmp_to_key to have old-style comparison functions work though.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def cmp_items(a, b):
    if a.foo > b.foo:
        return 1
    elif a.foo == b.foo:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

cmp_items_py3 = cmp_to_key(cmp_items)

alist.sort(key = cmp_items_py3)
```

Comment: `cmp_to_key` also works when used as a no-argument decorator (put `@cmp_to_key` on the line before your `def` for the comparing function) so you don't need to call `cmp_to_key` and assign the result yourself

Answer (score 13):

I know many have already posted some good answers. However I want to suggest one nice and easy method without importing any library.

```
l = [(2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)]
l.sort(key = lambda x: (-x[0], -x[1]) )
print(l)
l.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]) )
print(l)
```

Output will be

```
[(3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3)]
[(2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

The output will be sorted based on the order of the parameters we provided in the tuple format

Comment: For sorting, first, it will check the first item in the tuple and it will try to sort according to the sign you have given ('-' indicates reverse sorting). If it fails to sort using the first item, then it considers the second item in the tuple..and so on...

Answer (score 6):

Even better:

```
student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]

sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Taken from: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html