# How to sort a list containing alphanumeric values?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list that consists of details like this:

```
list1 = ["1", "100A", "342B", "2C", "132", "36", "302F"]
```

I want to sort this list, such that the values are in the following order:

```
list1 = ["1", "2C", "36", "100A", "132", "302F", "342B"]
```

Just doing `list1.sort()` obviously doesn't give the correct answer -
it gives:

```
list1 = ["1", "100A", "132", "2C", "36", "302F", "342B"]
```

I'm assuming this is because Python treats all these as strings directly.
However, I want to sort them based on their numeric value FIRST, and then the character that follows the number.

How do I proceed?

Comment: See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting) and define a custom compare function.

Comment: This is called **natural sort**. possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to use [**natural sort**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html):

```
import re

_nsre = re.compile('([0-9]+)')
def natural_sort_key(s):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list1 = ["1", "100A", "342B", "2C", "132", "36", "302F"]
>>> list1.sort(key=natural_sort_key)
>>> list1
['1', '2C', '36', '100A', '132', '302F', '342B']
```

This functions by splitting the elements into lists separating out the numbers and comparing them as integers instead of strings:

```
>>> natural_sort_key("100A")
['', 100, 'a']
>>> natural_sort_key("342B")
['', 342, 'b']
```

Note that this only works in Python3 if you are always comparing ints with ints and strings with strings, otherwise you get a `TypeError: unorderable types` exception.

Comment: Note that for Python 3 all items must have a similar structure.  `['a1', '2b']` would fail with a `TypeError`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: ah i forgot about that, thanks. I'll mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to find a way to convert your strings to numbers first. For example

```
import re
def convert(str):
    return int("".join(re.findall("\d*", str)))
```

and then you use it as a sort key:

```
list1.sort(key=convert)
```

Comment: There are some more natural sort solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort