# How to deal with filename reading convention when using cv2.videowriter

Tags: python, opencv, filenames

Essentially I have a directory of with images with the following naming convention frame{framenumber}.jpeg. However, when I implement the function below which aims to stitch these images into a video using the cv2 package there's this unanticipated behaviour where the files are read in the following order:
['frame0.jpg', 'frame1.jpg', frame10.jpg', '100.jpg', '101.jpg', '102.jpg', '103.jpg', 'frame104.jpg', 'frame105.jpg', 'frame106.jpg', 'frame107.jpg', 'frame108.jpg', 'frame109.jpg', 'frame11.jpg', 'frame110.jpg',...]
so at it no chronological and it looks kinda funny because at least every 10 frame is from a completely different segment of the video. Is there an obvious solution to this problem (some better way of reading in the images of some naming convention I'm not aware of)?

```
def makevideo():
    img_array = []
    filenames = [] 
    for filename in glob.glob(r'D:\Uni work\Engineering Mathematics Work\MDM3\Mojo\mojo_sperm_tracking_data_bristol\tp49\*.jpg'):
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers = img.shape
        size = (width,height)
        filenames.append(filename)
        img_array.append(img)
    
    print(filenames)   
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 60, size)

    for i in range(len(img_array)):
        out.write(img_array[i])
    out.release()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159707/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files on the filesystem are not sorted. You need thesort the resulting filenames yourself using the sorted() function:

```
import re
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts

 for filename in sorted(glob.glob(r'D:\Uni work\Engineering Mathematics Work\MDM3\Mojo\mojo_sperm_tracking_data_bristol\tp49\*.jpg'), key=numericalSort):
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution but unfortunately, it gives the same result as before. The only way I can think of is to use zero-filled numbers since it's the numbers <100 that are problematic.