# How to print files inside a folder in original order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm trying to print files present inside a folder in it's original order. Order inside folder [1.mp4 2.mp4 5.mp4 10.mp4 23.mp4]

Code I use:

```
targetFile = os.listdir(path)
for i in targetFile:
    print(i)
```

Output I get:
1.mp4
10.mp4
2.mp4
23.mp4
5.mp4

Output I expected:
1.mp4
2.mp4
5.mp4
10.mp4
23.mp4

How to fix it?

Comment: Files don't have an order.  Why do you expect there to be one?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33159106/1187415 and the linked questions.

Comment: I believe you need files sorted by name. Just change to `sorted(os.listdir(path))`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you seek is ordering the list as if they were an `int`. At the moment the result you are getting is based on how a `string` is sorted. If you can figure out how to change the [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html?highlight=sort) in sorting `os.listdir(path)`, your problem is solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33138704)

Comment: @buhtz true, it does not give the solution, but it shows the way how to solve it. For such a simple problem, I'd say that is appropriate.