# Alphanumeric sorting in Python and negative numbers

Tags: python, sorting

I have a fairly simple list (a number followed by a sentence), here in the right order:

```
-347 a negative number
-100 another negative number
-25 and again, a negative number
17 some text
25 foo bar
100 two same texts
100 two same texts (almost)
350 a positive number
```

I need to sort that list each time a new item is added.

I searched S.O. and found that answer :

[Sorting in python - how to sort a list containing alphanumeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366517/sorting-in-python-how-to-sort-a-list-containing-alphanumeric-values)

The code I used is freakish’s, which goes :

```
import re
def convert(str):
    return int("".join(re.findall("\d*", str)))

list1.sort(key=convert)
```

In order to better explain my problem, I shuffled the list and ran the code.

The result was :

```
17 some text
-25 and again, a negative number
25 foo bar
100 two same texts (almost)
100 two same texts
-100 another negative number
-347 a negative number
350 a positive number
```

What went wrong ? What is the precision in the code that would sort naturally the negative numbers?

Comment: `'-'` isn't a digit, so it isn't matched by `'\d'`. Consequently, your pattern match only finds full numbers. Side notes: If your input string is e.g.`'1 this is line 00001'` it will be sorted last by your key. And `''` matches `'\d*'`, but `int('')` raises `ValueError`.

Comment: You could separate the negative and positive before running, and glue them afterwards, making the negative ones reversed and at the top.

Comment: You could change your convert function to `return int(str.split()[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to split the string to individual words, and then sort by the first word converted to an `int`:

```
list1.sort(key = lambda x : int(x.split(" ")[0]))
```

**EDIT:**

As Keatinge, the above solution won't properly handle two strings that start with the same number. Using the entire string as a secondary search term should solve this issue:

```
list1.sort(key = lambda x : (int(x.split(" ")[0]), x)
```

Comment: This wont handle two strings that start with the same number but contain different text afterward

Comment: @Keatinge good point! Using the string itself as a secondary search term should do the trick though - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

Sort can accept a tuple, so first sort by the number, then by the text after

```
list_text = """-347 a negative number
-100 another negative number
-25 and again, a negative number
17 some text
25 foo bar
100 two same texts
100 two same texts (almost)
350 a positive number"""

list1 = list_text.split("\n")

list1.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x.split()[0]), x.split(" ",1)))

print("\n".join(list1))
```

Comment: To avoid first join you can pass 1 as argument to split - it will limit number of splits

Comment: @Keatinge first of all, thanks ; but I get an error on the [list1 = list_text.split("\n")] line : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I do not understand why (my Python skills are not worth mentioning)

Comment: @ThG Just use the last two lines, the others are for a runnable example so everyone can run it and test it

Comment: @Keatinge : It works. And now I am embarrassed : I have 2 good answers and I already "ticked" Murelnik's. And I do not know how to share my compliments on S.O. Thank you very much anyway.