# Python: How to sort alphanumerically filenames in a folder?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I'm using `python 2.7` and I'm trying to read filenames in a folder, sorted in aphanumberical order.

My code is:

```
filenamelist=[]
txt_path = 'decoded'

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(txt_path)):
  with open(txt_path+"/"+filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "Total Time" in line:

            filenamelist.append(filename)
```

When I print `filenamelist` I get the following:

['pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_**level_0**_192x144_15_50_dec.txt', 'p
irkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_**level_10**_192x144_25_42_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_**level_11**_192x144_25_38_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_12_192x144_25_34_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_13_192x144_25_30_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_14_192x144_25_26_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_15_192x144_25_22_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_1_192x144_15_46_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_2_192x144_15_42_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_3_192x144_15_38_dec.txt', 'pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_192x144_Filters_OFF_level_4_192x144_15_34_dec.txt', ...]

As can be seen, this is not sorted. I want to get `level_0, level_1, level_2, ..., level_9, level_10...]`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366517/sorting-in-python-how-to-sort-a-list-containing-alphanumeric-values

Comment: @bakaDev Thank you! That's solves my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@bakaDev` this is the solution to my problem:

```
import re #for natural sorting

filenamelist=[]
txt_path = 'decoded'

_nsre = re.compile('([0-9]+)')
def natural_sort_key(s):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]   

fnlist = os.listdir(txt_path)

fnlist.sort(key=natural_sort_key)

for filename in fnlist):
  with open(txt_path+"/"+filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "Total Time" in line:

            filenamelist.append(filename)
```