# sort numerically then alphnumerically on the same column

Tags: python, shell, sorting, ubuntu, unix

I have very large data which I want to sort on

- column 1: numerically and then alphanumerically
- then on column 2: numerically.

So, my final output would be something like this:

```
1    11  
1    13
1    15
2    3
2    5
chr2   6
chr2   15
chr15   3
chr15   9
```

I am using `sort` on unix. But, I either keep getting **chr2** on the top or on the bottom with any sort I try. Here are some of the sort I tried: which fail to give me the desired output:

```
sort -V -k1,1n -k2n final_merged.txt > merged-sort.txt
sort -k1,1n -k2n final_merged.txt > merged-sort.txt 
sort -k1,1h -k2n final_merged.txt > merged-sort.txt
sort -k1,1 -k2n final_merged.txt > merged-sort.txt
```

**Post edit:** Any way to fix this issue without overloading the memory while using

- sort or other unix utilities
- python

Thanks,

Comment: Is the prefix in column 1 always `chr` (or at least the same number of characters)?

Comment: it could be different. This sorting has been giving me trouble all day. I read the several sort tutorials but can not fix this.

Comment: @chepner : any way it is possible to fix this up.

Comment: you want a numeric sort, but 'chr2' is not a number. you need a preprocessing step of splitting the first column into 2 columns, one of 'chr' (or blank:'' in the case of just a number) and then then number. probably sed or awk can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sort -k1,2 -V final_merged.txt
```

Running this using your sample data gives me:

```
1    11
1    13
1    15
2    3
2    5
chr2   6
chr2   15
chr15   3
chr15   9
```

Comment: perfect. I should have moved that `V`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a numeric sort, but 'chr2' is not a number. you need a preprocessing step of splitting the first column into 2 columns, the text part and the number part.

`gawk 'match($1, /([^0-9])*([0-9]*)/, a) {print a[1], a[2], $2}' /tmp/abc | 
sort -t ' ' -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n`

use gawk to split on a regex, non numeric then numeric, then column 2 (separated by single spaces now).

Sort on single space separated columns.

`gawk '{print $1 $2, $3}'` to recombine the columns.

You may need to modify these to maintain whatever whitespace is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution:

Initialize [Natural Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366517/sorting-in-python-how-to-sort-a-list-containing-alphanumeric-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```
import re

_nsre = re.compile('([0-9]+)')
def natural_sort_key(s):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]
```

Then sort as you wanted:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (natural_sort_key(str(item[0])), item[1]))
```

sorting primarily on `item[0]` with `natural sort`, then on `item[1]` numerically.

Comment: OP states that the collection will not fit in memory, this python is even asking for the data to be in memory twice