# python: Can't make list.sort to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, python-3.5

```
def sort_line(line1,line2):

    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line1:
        mn1 = min(x1,x2)
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line2:
        mn2 = min(x1,x2)
    return mn1 < mn2 

lines.sort(sort_line)
```

Here lines has 4 int in every row. From what I understood from python wiki is that I need to pass a compare function as argument in the sort() function. But I get the following error,

```
<ipython-input-107-b0e2f3c756cf> in draw_lines(img, lines, color, thickness)
     69     """
     70 
---> 71     lines.sort(sort_line)
     72 
     73     for line in lines:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type function)
```

I tried with sorted() but couldn't make it work either.

Python and anaconda version

> Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016,
>   11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I'm running the code in jupyter notebook.

My implementation I think is same as the following question but mine doesn't work.

[Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

After following Martijn's answer I modified my code to this

```
lineList = lines.tolist()  //lines is a numpy array so I converted it to list
print ('lineList: ',lineList)
lineList.sort(key=lambda l: min(l[0], l[2]))
lines = np.array(lineList)
```

Gives me the following error

```
<ipython-input-115-06412e8f5aba> in <lambda>(l)
     72     lineList = lines.tolist()
     73     print ('lineList: ',lineList)
---> 74     lineList.sort(key=lambda l: min(l[0], l[1]))
     75     lines = np.array(lineList)
     76 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: But doesn't the sort function requires a compare function as argument? and I'm passing the compare function in the sort function.

Comment: You appear to be expecting sorting to use a `cmp()` function. It does not; you are only given **one** element and are expected to give a sort key. You are getting confused with Python 2 here.

Comment: You appear to be reading the *The Old Way Using the cmp Parameter* section on the wiki, that option is basically gone in Python 3 (or use the *slow* [`functools.cmp_to_key()` wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key)).

Comment: All this *is* clearly documented in the sorting howto however, as well as in the [`list.sort()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making several mistakes. You didn't read the documentation close enough; the `cmp` function option is gone in Python 3. You also implemented your `cmp` function incorrectly, and last but not least, you don't need to use a `cmp` function at all, you can use a [`key` function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) to extract the minimum of the two exact values in the lists you are sorting.

You need to pay close attention to the section you appear to be reading, [*The Old Way Using the cmp Parameter*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter):

> In Py3.0, the `cmp` parameter was removed entirely (as part of a larger effort to simplify and unify the language, eliminating the conflict between rich comparisons and the `__cmp__` methods).

The error message is a little confusing here, but `list.sort()` takes *no* positional arguments. From the [`list.sort()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> `sort(*, key=None, reverse=None)`

The `*` indicates no positional arguments are accepted, and there is no `cmp` option.

Going back to the Sorting Howto:

> When porting code from Python 2.x to 3.x, the situation can arise when you have the user supplying a comparison function and you need to convert that to a key function. The following wrapper makes that easy to do:
>
> ```
> def cmp_to_key(mycmp):
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> In Python 2.7, the `cmp_to_key()` tool was added to the `functools` module.

and again from the `list.sort()` documentation:

> The `functools.cmp_to_key()` utility is available to convert a 2.x style `cmp` function to a key function.

You also incorrectly implemented your `cmp` function; there is no need to iterate, and you have to return `-1`, `0` or `1` to indicate relative order (so you would have to use `cmp(min(list1), min(list2))` if there still was a built-in `cmp()` function).

However, you can sort your data **without** a (slow) `cmp` function. All you need to do is to extract the `min()` of the two values of each list, in a sort key:

```
lines.sort(key=lambda l: min(l[0], l[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand now. I want to sort the list according to smallest x values in each row. My code for comp function was wrong and I modified it now. So for each row in list the row with smallest x (between each x1,x2 in every row) should be the first element after sort and then the next. But using min would return the smallest between all 4 elements right? In that case it wont' serve my purpose :( But thanks very much now I understand the reason of the error.

Comment: @Tahlil: I saw that edit and already corrected for it. Just have a function (provided by a `lambda` expression in my example) that returns the minimum of those two values.

Comment: I'm getting array index out of bound error now with the lambda function. Edited the question with the error. I'm very new in python :( Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Tahlil: then you have entries with fewer than 3 elements. Either use `lambda l: (len(l) > 2, min(l[0], l[2]))` to sort those shorter lists separately, or remove such entries from the input list first. You didn't give us any sample data to sort, so we can only *guess* at your exact data structures here.

Comment: printing linesList shows every row has 4 elements. The output of the print just before the lambda function line is: lineList:  [[[515, 327, 854, 538]], [[774, 501, 832, 539]], [[499, 320, 763, 492]], [[310, 423, 446, 331]], [[319, 425, 454, 327]], [[524, 333, 853, 539]], [[730, 472, 796, 514]], [[698, 451, 758, 489]], [[361, 392, 418, 351]], [[498, 320, 558, 359]], [[318, 425, 415, 355]], [[612, 394, 828, 535]], [[387, 370, 436, 336]]]

Comment: @Tahlil: no, each list has just **one** element, which is another list. You may want to fix that and remove the outer lists, they are entirely redundant. Otherwise use `lambda l: min(l[0][0], l[0][2])` to address the single list in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> sort() accepts two arguments that can only be passed by keyword (keyword-only arguments): *key* and *reverse*.

The *cmp* parameter only exists in Python 2, it is generally considered as a deprecated usage.