# Sort list by a function with several parameters

Tags: python

How can I sort some objects on the following list with the result of the `function`?

```
sorted_list = []
for c in objects:
    sorted_list.insert(c)

    sorted_list.sort(function(c))
```

Something like a map

Example:

```
objects = [node3, node2, node1, node4]

def function (node, player):
   if (node == node1): return 1
   else if (node == node2): return 2
   else if (node == node3): return 3
   else if (node == node4): return 4
```

output:

```
objects = [node1, node2, node3, node4]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ranking function as the sorting key:

```
sorted_list.sort(key=lambda node: function(node, player))
```

I don't know why you pass `player` as parameter if you're not using it. If you remove it, the key will be even simpler:

```
sorted_list.sort(key=function)
```