# Sorting a sorted list using a specific dimension as the key

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of points, where each point is *d-dimensional*. The list is currently sorted with the regular `list.sort()` function, which means the keys are prioritized from the first dimension to the last in order.
I want to take the list and sort it while prioritizing the 2nd key, running a code on it, then prioritizing the 3nd key and so on.
Is there a more efficient way than just using the sort() function with a specific key?

Because I know the points are sorted at each step with priority to the k-th dimension and I want to sort it by the next one, so I think it might be possible to manage the list and sort it just like combining a bunch of sorted lists in **O(n)** instead of **O(nlogn)** for the regular `sort()`. Is it possible, or am I mistaken?
If possible, a help with implementation in python would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Example of a list after the `list.sort()` function:

```
[(-3, -5, -5, -2), (-3, -4, 2, -2), (-3, 2, 5, 2), (0, 0, -5, 1), (1, -3, 2, 0), (2, -1, 0, 0), (2, 3, -1, 0), (4, 1, -2, 1), (5, -3, -1, 1), (5, 1, -2, -2)]
```

Comment: Does the dimensions have any intrinsic relationship (e.g., values in dimension 2 are always smaller than values in dimension 3)? Also, this code you run after sorting takes into account only the sorted dimension or it uses all the others dimensions too?

Comment: can you post an example of your data point

Comment: Maybe you should override the sorting function. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting

Comment: The dimensions don't have any intrinsic relationship other than being all floats and my code takes into account only the sorted dimension.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input, and your desired output? I can't tell if the example you've supplied is the input or the desired output. And your explanation is unclear.

Comment: Note that postulate (it should be possible to sort O(n) that way) is false. That would be implementing a fusion-partition sort, partition being made from kth keys, recursive sorting from k+1th, etc. So, it is still O(n.log(n)), and even worse, because of the non-optimal constraint on how we partition data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1:])
```

Comment: I think this is what the regular sort() function does, just ignoring the 1st dimension. I will need to sort the list for every dimension in order, so just calling sort D times with different keys won't help in improving the efficiency as I wish to do.

Comment: please provide a better example than, like with 3 dimensions( that fit your data)

Comment: add desired output also please

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you can sort the `n` elements `k` times, dimension by dimension, in less than `O(k.n lgn)`, e.g `O(n (lg n + k-1))` (sort the first dimension in `O(n lg n)` and then in `O(n)`).

Then take a list of `m` numbers, split it into `sqrt(m)` chunks of (roughly) `sqrt(m)` elements. You have `k = n = sqrt(m)`. Sort the zipped (as in Python) chunks in `O(k (lg n + k-1) = O(sqrt(m) (lg (sqrt(m)) + sqrt(m)-1))`. Since `sqrt` wins over `lg`, your chunks are sorted in `O(m)`. You have `sqrt(m)` sorted lists that you can merge in `O(n lg k) = O(sqrt(m) lg (sqrt(m)))` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm). This merge time is less than `O(m)`. Putting the blocks together, your list is sorted in `O(m)`.

The `O (n lg n)` boudnary is generally accepted, thus it is reasonable to say that you won't find a way to achieve the `k` sorts in less than `O(k.n lgn)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1:])
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: OP made clear they already know about `key`, and they didn't want it. A 3 years old answer already proposed that anyway, and was already rebuked by OP. Please, elaborate why do you think your version is new and better than already existing answer?