# How to sort so that strings starting with digit as a first character moves to the end of the list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a problem where I couldn;t find a way to sort a list of strings in such a way that the values that starts a digit sorted in the end, and value that starts with letters are at the start of the list

I have tried using `sort` and `sorted` methods with lambda but its always sort with numbers at the start of the list.

Here is what I have tried

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = ["9 1 7 2", "hell bag", "8 7", "deserve respect three", "phone exit retired"]
    print(sorted(l))
```

and this gives me following output,,

```
['8 7', '9 1 7 2', 'deserve respect three', 'hell bag', 'phone exit retired']
```

I want following output instead,

```
['deserve respect three', 'hell bag', 'phone exit retired', '8 7', '9 1 7 2']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting

Comment: I am sorry but i don't see any duplication between the two? I have already tried `lambda` with `key` but it allows me to provide what key to use for sorting but not `alpha` or `numeric`

Comment: So show a [mcve] of that. What do you think is the limitation of key that means you can't implement what you describe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reversed()` method to get your target result, like this:
`print(list(reversed(sorted(l))))`

output is:
`['phone exit retired', 'hell bag', 'deserve respect three', '9 1 7 2', '8 7']`