# How do I sort multi-dimensional array elements like this?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list like this:

```
[
  [
    ['KAD', 'PENGENALAN'],
    ['0.95', '0.98'],
    [[106, 16, 202, 48], [214, 14, 524, 50]],
    [106, 214]
  ],
  [
    ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'],
    ['0.95', '0.98', '0.99'],
    [[222, 16, 202, 48], [55,14, 524, 50]], [89, 14, 524, 50]]
    [222, 55, 89]
  ]

]
```

I want to sort items per line by 4th element.

4th element is `[106, 214]` and `[222, 55, 89]`

First list is already sorted according to 4th element. I want to sort 2nd list.

In the second list, I want to sort by small to big. I want to sort using `[222,55,89]`

Expected output is:

```
[
  [
    ['KAD', 'PENGENALAN'],
    ['0.95', '0.98'],
    [[106, 16, 202, 48], [214, 14, 524, 50]],
    [106, 214]
  ],
  [
    ['word2', 'word3', 'word'],
    ['0.98', '0.99','0.95'],
    [[55,14, 524, 50]], [89, 14, 524, 50],[222, 16, 202, 48]]
    [55, 89,222]
  ]

]
```

I don't know how I can do this. But can I use `zip()` and sort? Just giving you some ideas

Comment: I do not understand how sorting changes the three strings `['KUALA', 'TERENGGANU', '20050']` to a single string `'20050 KUALA TERENGGANU'`

Comment: "I think the code will be ..." - if you have an idea, why not code it and see whether it works or not? Giving us a [mcve] would increase the chances to get an answer.

Comment: The first word is linked to first left, second word is linked to second left

Comment: KUALA = 112, TERENGGANU = 222, 20050 = 22 left value

Comment: You can copy/paste the row list and reproduce @ThomasWeller. How to sort this is my main question. I think I provided all information neccessory.

Comment: Basically sort values of first & second list by third list.

Comment: Can I do something like `zip()` and sort?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I will make the question simple

Comment: Edited the question @ThomasWeller

Comment: Please help, if you are free. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the answer.

It is something like

```
finalList = []
for i in range(len(text_line)):
    zipped_pairs = zip(text_line[i][3],text_line[i][0], text_line[i][1],text_line[i][2])
    tempList = []
    for a,b,c,d in sorted(zipped_pairs):
        tempList.append([b,c,d])
    finalList.append(np.array(tempList).T)
```

Need to arrange it properly