# Custom Sort the list in ascending order with using sorted functions in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

## Custom Sort #

**Description**

Sort a list of integers basis the remainder they leave when divided by 5 in an ascending order, i.e. the number that leaves a lower remainder when divided by 5 should come before the number which leaves a higher remainder.

Hint: Use the appropriate ‘key’ in the sorted() function. If two integers leave the same remainder then their order — as in the original list — should be preserved.

Examples:

**Input 1:**

`[1, 9, 35, 12, 13, 21, 10]`

**Output 1:**

`[35, 10, 1, 21, 12, 13, 9]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sorted([1, 9, 35, 12, 13, 21, 10], key=lambda x: ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876197", x % 5))
[35, 10, 1, 21, 12, 13, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a lambda expression for your [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function:

```
l = [1, 9, 35, 12, 13, 21, 10] 
sorted(l,key=lambda elem: elem%5)
```

Output:

```
[35, 10, 1, 21, 12, 13, 9]
```

Comment: @CodePope user13526138 doesn't have enough reputation to downvote

Comment: @komatiraju032 Hmm, then I wonder who has downvoted this answer, while upvoting the other one, although mine is correct and have been sent first.