# Adapting the same sorting order from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing numbers and one containing users. The first element of the first list belongs to the first element of the second list and so on. I  then want to sort the number list using `sort()` and want the usernames to still match with the numbers they had before.

from:

```
users = ["max", "david", "freddy"]

numbers = [9, 3, 10]
```

to:

```
users = ["david", "max", "freddy"]

numbers = [3, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Why not just use a dict (key value pair) to map these numbers to users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort two lists (which reference each other) in the exact same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298/how-to-sort-two-lists-which-reference-each-other-in-the-exact-same-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> users = ["max", "david", "Freddy"]
>>> numbers = [9, 3, 10]
>>> sorted_users = [u for _, u in sorted(zip(numbers, users)]
>>> sorted_users
['david', 'max', 'freddy']
```

Comment: The `lambda` is unnecessary. It will sort by the first element first by default.

Comment: True, removed it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest grouping your values together in a list of **tuples** or **dictionaries**:

```py
data = [
    ('max',    9),
    ('david',  3),
    ('freddy', 10)
]
```

and then you can use [custom sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11850425/9063935) to sort this list:

```py
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This way your data is stored in a way which keeps their relationship.

To use dictionaries instead requires this simple change:

```py
data = [
    {'name': 'max',    'number': 9},
    {'name': 'david',  'number': 3},
    {'name': 'freddy', 'number': 10}
]
```

and then change your sort code to

```py
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['number'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the two into one list, sort based on the number, then unzip them:

```py
users = ["max", "david", "freddy"]
numbers = [9, 3, 10]

zipped = sorted(zip(numbers, users), key=lambda x: x[0])

numbers, users = zip(*zipped)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dictionary for user numbers and user names

```
users = ["max", "david", "freddy"]

numbers = [9, 3, 10]

dictionary = {users[i]: numbers[i] for i in range(len(numbers))} 

{'max': 9, 'david': 3, 'freddy': 10}
```

and then sort the dictionary and convert back to lists. \

Answer (score 0):

Using the right combination of zip and map, you can do this in one line:

```
users   = ["max", "david", "freddy"]
numbers = [9, 3, 10]

numbers,users = map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(numbers,users))))

print(users)   # ['david', 'max', 'freddy'] 
print(numbers) # [3, 9, 10]
```