# Sorting a list according to the second integer

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list according to the second item. I have written this code out, but it isn't sorting them properly.

```
import random

d2 = []
for i in range (12):
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    y = x
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    d2.append([x,y])
```

I am having trouble with this part where I need to have it sort it out. It sorts the first two lists but then it stops working. What's wrong with my code?

```
def sortlist(A):
    l = len(A)
    for i in range(0, l):
        for j in range(0, l-i-1):
            if (A[j][1] > A[j + 1][1]):
                tempo = A[j]
                A[j]= A[j + 1]
                A[j + 1]= tempo
                return A

A = d2
print(sortlist(A))
```

Comment: can you just make a new list that is equal to the first one but delete the first item, then sort that and append it to the list with the first existing item?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Comment: @couka The OP does **not** ask how to sort a list, but what is wrong with their already implemented algorithm.

Comment: @Countour-Integral Mr. Quadri blew it.

Comment: Your `return A` has the wrong indentation -- it should at the same indentation as `l = len(A)`. I had a much longer answer I was writing until the question was closed on me. You also have unnecessary assignments -- see if you can find them yourself.

Comment: @Countour-Integral Ok. My answer is "Everything, check this to see how to do it properly in Python" then. Debugging code that's conceptually bad isn't valuable for the community.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's `sorted`, and set your custom `key` function to specify based on what the list elements should be sorted by.

```
# sort the list based on each element's second integer (elem[1])
sorted(d2, key=lambda elem: elem[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you the `key` argument of `sort` or `sorted` to to sort by that key. The key you need in this case it `itemgetter(1)`, so for example:

```
import operator

data = [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 7), ('d', 6)]
data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

# data is now [('b', 4), ('a', 5), ('d', 6), ('c', 7)]
```

BTW, `operator.itemgetter(1)` does the same thing as `lambda x: x[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what youre after?

```
list1 = [10, 5, 2, 3]
list2 = list(list1)
del list2[0]
list2.sort()

for i in range(0, len(list2)):
    list1[i+1] = list2[i]

print(list1)
```

Output: `[10, 2, 3, 5]`