# Sorting two lists of lists in identical manner

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort two lists of lists. Each one is a string.

```
list1 = [[john, 456, 789], [bill, 483, 293], [jack, 292, 483]]
list2 = [[bill, 483, 293], [john, 2982, 272] [jack, 237, 411]]
```

As you can see the two lists of lists have a different order, and each name has different numbers.

I'm looking to create a sorted version of each list, sorted by the name (the first index of each inner list) ONLY. So it would look like:

```
list1 = [[john, 456, 789], [bill, 483, 293], [jack, 292, 483]]
list2 = [[john, 2982, 272], [bill, 483, 293],  [jack, 299, 411]]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are ``john``, ``bill``, ``jack`` strings or variables?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want to sort by the name, however you demonstrated the results as john, bill and jack, while sorting [by the ABC] should result in Bill, Jack and John.

they also might just be variables that contain other strings, nobody knows.

Comment: @Jonathan1609 i'll edit for clarification.

Comment: Also consider simply storing one or both sets of data in a dictionary e.g. `dict2['john'] = (456, 789)`, unless you absolutely need both in lists.

Comment: What you are looking for could be [sorting with a custom key](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). There has been [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850552/14426823) on this. You would do this: `list1.sort(key=lambda arr: arr[0])`

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam This will work thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the names are all strings, you can sort `list2` based on the order of the names in `list1`:

```
list1 = [['john', 456, 789], ['bill', 483, 293], ['jack', 292, 483]]
list2 = [['bill', 483, 293], ['john', 2982, 272], ['jack', 237, 411]]

names = [l[0] for l in list1]
list2.sort(key=lambda x: names.index(x[0]))
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[['john', 2982, 272], ['bill', 483, 293], ['jack', 237, 411]]
```

The code will still work if the names are variables not strings.