# Sort a list with which values contains (str) numbers or letters

Tags: python

How can I sort a list that contains string numbers and letters in such a way that sorts numbers numerically and then letters alphabetically?

```
my_list = ["10","2","1","5","a","b","c"]

disable_sorted_list
"1","2","5","10","a","b","c"
```

Comment: As this looks like homework, here is another question which should point you to the solution! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting

Answer (score 5):

Sort with an appropriate key function:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda s: (not s.isdigit(), int(s) if s.isdigit() else s))
['1', '2', '5', '10', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

The sorting key `(not s.isdigit(), int(s) if s.isdigit() else s)` is a pair (tuple)

```
(bool, str|int)
```

Since tuples are sorted lexicographically (compare element-wise, decide on first not-equal element), the numbers come first (`False < True`).

We convert the numbers to integers in the sorting key so they are not sorted alphabetically

```
3 < 10  # but 
"10" < "3"
```

Comment: This is super clever. I would never have thought like this but its so good.

Comment: @AyushGupta added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (not optimized but easy to understand) :

```py
my_list = ["10","2","1","5","a","b","c"]
int_list = [];
str_list = [];
final_list = [];

# separate integers and string in two different arrays
for element in my_list:
  if(element.isdigit()):
    int_list.append(int(element))
  else:
    str_list.append(element)

# sort integers array and strings array
int_list.sort()
str_list.sort()

# cast the integers list into strings list 
int_list = list(map(str, int_list))

# add both list to the final list.
final_list = int_list + str_list

print(final_list)
```