# sorting a list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I have two list:
`array1 = [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1,1, -1, 0, 1] array2 = [0, 1, -1]`  
I want to return another list  based on how the second list is sorted for example the output of the two lists above would be

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

this is what I currently have however only [0,0,0,0] print can anyone tell me what im doing wrong:

```
def patternSort(arr1, arr2):
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    arr3 = []
    while i < len(arr1):
        if arr1[i] == arr2[counter]:
            arr3.append(arr1[i])
            
        i += 1
    print(arr3)


array1 = [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1,1, -1, 0, 1]
array2 = [0, 1, -1] 

patternSort(array1, array2)
```

Comment: So you want to count the number of 0's and output that many 0's.  Then count the 1's and output that many 1's.  Then count the -1's and output that many -1s.  For my first step, I'd call `collections.Counter(array1)`, and then iterate through `array2` to generate the output.

Answer (score 1):

If `array2` is relatively short and you're not worried about the time complexity of searching it, this can be accomplished succinctly by using a custom comparison key with the existing [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin:

```
>>> sorted(array1, key=array2.index)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Note that this performs a linear search of `array2` for every comparison during sorting.
If you need something more performant, you can resolve the comparison keys ahead of time and store them in a dictionary:

```
order_map = {k: order for order, k in enumerate(array2)}
sorted(array1, key=order_map.get)  # [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: what does key=lambda x: mean?

Comment: @sadboy99 See [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)