# Python: Typing a lambda function for use with sorted

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, mypy, typing

Given the following Python file:

```
class SomeValue:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

some_values = sorted([SomeValue(3), SomeValue(4)], lambda v: v.value)
```

When running `mypy` on this, I get

```
demo.py:5: error: No overload variant of "sorted" matches argument types "List[SomeValue]", "Callable[[Any], Any]"
demo.py:5: note: Possible overload variants:
demo.py:5: note:     def [SupportsLessThanT <: SupportsLessThan] sorted(Iterable[SupportsLessThanT], *, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...) -> List[SupportsLessThanT]
demo.py:5: note:     def [_T] sorted(Iterable[_T], *, key: Callable[[_T], SupportsLessThan], reverse: bool = ...) -> List[_T]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I don't really understand what makes `mypy` unhappy.

Comment: check this if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting

Comment: Look up the function signature for `sorted()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

```
some_values = sorted([SomeValue(3), SomeValue(4)], key=lambda v: v.value)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! My autocompletion indicated, that `key` is simply the second parameter, not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: `key` is a **keyword argument** so `key=func` is necessary.