# How to return a list of top 3 userIds in descending order from JSON dataset

Tags: python, list

[
{
"id": 23456,
"pieceId": 25395616,
"status": 10800,
"userId": 911,
"startTime": 1490989764,
"endTime": 1491001113
},
{
"id": 333883698,
"pieceId": 25390812,
"status": 10451,
"userId": 88738562,
"startTime": 1491004450,
"endTime": 1491004579

Comment: How do you define the top 3? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using customized sorting and getting a sublist from the sorted list.

`key=lamda x:-x["userId"]` is customized sort function.

The minus before the x means decease the "userId" attribute.
You can research how to custom sort in python at [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: -x["userId"])
result = list[0:3]
```

if your data type is a string, you can use it before sorting the list.

```
import json
list  = json.loads(stringData)
```