# Python order list by datetime then by duration

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a list like:

```py
a = [
{
"dt_1":datetime.datetime(...),
"duration_milliseconds":<int>
},
{
"dt_1":datetime.datetime(...),
"duration_milliseconds":<int>
},
{
"dt_1":datetime.datetime(...),
"duration_milliseconds":<int>
},
{
"dt_1":datetime.datetime(...),
"duration_milliseconds":<int>
}
]
```

I want to sort this list this way: First sort by dt_1 (older datetimes first), then if some dt_1's are the same sort by duration_milliseconds (little durations first).

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Python list sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850425/custom-python-list-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

The `key=` argument for `list.sort()` and `sorted()` defines a function to use as a sort key for a given item in the iterable, and returning a tuple from that function does what you want, since tuples are compared item-wise:

```
a.sort(key=lambda p: (p["dt_1"], p["duration_milliseconds"]))
```

Comment: One extra question: Is it possible to except one list item from order (let it be the last item)? I know i can permantly delete it but is there any easier way?

Comment: It'll probably be easiest to `pop` the last item out, sort the rest, then `append` it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different ordering for every value you need to order in reverse by the negative of the `int`s

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (x['dt_1'], -x['duration_milliseconds']), reverse=True)
```