# overriding __cmp__ python function

Tags: python

Hi I am overriding `__cmp__` . If the second object passed is `None`, or if it is not an instance of `someClass`, then it returns `-1`.

I don't understand what exactly is happening here.

```
class someClass():
    def __cmp__(self, obj):
        if obj == None:
            return -1
        if not isinstance(obj, someClass):
            return -1
```

My test function:

```
def test_function(self):  
        obj1 = someClass()
        self.assertTrue(obj1 < None)
        # I get true.
        self.assertTrue(obj1 > None)
        # I get failure as False is returned.
```

Could anyone please explain to me:

- What are the return values?
- How is it deciding whether it will return `True` or `False` when the comparison signs are changed?

Comment: class someClass():  def __cmp__(self, obj):

Comment: ok let me edit the question code to avoid any confusion

Comment: Regardless of the error you are seeing you compare method would never return true. This means that your compare function defines no strict order.

Comment: Are you sure that `test_function` belongs to  `someClass`?

Comment: test_function is written in separate test file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `obj` is `None`, your program will return -1, while returning a negative integer means `self < obj`, so `obj1 < None` is `True`, and `obj1 > None` is `false`.

Comment: I din't understand how you have made the conclusion that     obj1 > None is false.

Comment: @PrashantKumar, actually the python don't care what the operator is, it just calculate `cmp(obj1,None)` and see what value will be returned, in your case, the value is -1, so the interpreter tells that `obj1 > None` is false.

Answer (score 8):

The convention for `__cmp__` is:

```
a < b : return -1
a = b : return 0
a > b : return 1
```

This of course makes only sense if both `a` and `b` are of compatible types, say numbers. If you have a 'corner case', where `a` or `b` is either None or incompatible (`not instanceof`), you should report an error, as this is a programming error in the *use* of the comparison operators on your `someClass` instance.

It is possible to implement *any* behaviour with `__cmp__`, but a comparison with None the way described by the OP will eventually lead to strange behaviour and bugs.

see also: [__lt__ instead of __cmp__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1061283/1689451) 
`http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__`

Comment: And any two objects should compare the opposite if they are passed in the other way around. Otherwise some assumptions that Python makes about orders are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), you'll see that the `cmp` function return `-1` if `self < other`.

Since `__cmp__(obj, None) == -1`, it assumed that `obj < None`.

My guess if `__cmp__(obj, None)` should return `1` as any object is superior to no object :)

Comment: sorry it din't help. My question is from what we made the conclusion that (obj1 < None) will get True and (obj1 > None) will get False.