# Sorting a list of objects, each containing a list

Tags: python, sorting

I'm writing a gin card game that deals with sets and melds of cards. A set is 3 or 4 cards with the same rank (i.e. 9c,9d,9h). A meld is a run of cards of the same rank (i.e. 8c,9c,10c). I want to sort a combined list of melds and sets.

Cards are represented like so:

```
class Card:
  def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
```

Cards are stored in CardGroups like so:

```
class CardGroup:
  def __init__(self, card_list):
    self.cards = []
    for c in card_list:
      self.cards.append(c)
```

Here's an example with the hand **2c,2h,2d,4h,5d,5s,5c,6c,7c,8c:**

The melds in this hand all deal with clubs: **(5c,6c,7c)** and **(6c,7c,8c)**. The sets are **(2c,2d,2h)** and **(5c,5d,5s)**.

The resulting combined list might combine like so (melds, then sets):

```
unsorted_list = [ CardGroup([Card(5,'c'), Card(6,'c'), Card(7,'c')], 
                  CardGroup([Card(6,'c'), Card(7,'c'), Card(8,'c')],
                  CardGroup([Card(2,'c'), Card(2,'d'), Card(2,'h')], 
                  CardGroup([Card(5,'c'), Card(5,'d'), Card(5,'s')] ]
```

The resulting combined list **should exist** like so (card by card comparison):

```
sorted_list   = [ CardGroup([Card(2,'c'), Card(2,'d'), Card(2,'h')], 
                  CardGroup([Card(5,'c'), Card(5,'d'), Card(5,'s')],
                  CardGroup([Card(5,'c'), Card(6,'c'), Card(7,'c')], 
                  CardGroup([Card(6,'c'), Card(7,'c'), Card(8,'c')] ]
```

Note that the second and third CardGroup both start with **5c**. It is important that these are sorted correctly. In the case that we have a 4-set like **2c,3c,4c,5c** we also implicitly have a 3-set of **2c,3c,4c**. When sorting these two, we want the 3-set to come before the 4-set.

Things I've Tried:

```
unsorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.cards)
unsorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.cards[0])
unsorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: tuple(x.cards))
```

Thank you for the help!

Edit: Using a comparison operator was suggested as an answer. Here are the unit tests for such a solution:

```
Class TestCard:
    def test___cmp__(self):
        card1 = Card(5, 'd')
        card2 = Card(6, 'c')
        card3 = Card(6, 's')

        self.assertLessEqual(card1.__cmp__(card2), -1)
        self.assertLessEqual(card1.__cmp__(card3), -1)
        self.assertEqual(card1.__cmp__(card1), 0)

        self.assertGreaterEqual(card2.__cmp__(card1), 1)
        self.assertLessEqual(card2.__cmp__(card3), -1)

        self.assertGreaterEqual(card3.__cmp__(card1), 1)
        self.assertGreaterEqual(card3.__cmp__(card2), 1)
```

Comment: Probably better to define comparison operations in your classes. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908933/overriding-cmp-python-function)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might help:

```
class Card:
  # ...
  def __cmp__(self, other):
    r = self.rank.__cmp__(other.rank)
    if not r:
      return self.suit.__cmp__(other.suit)
    return r

class CardGroup:
  # ...
  def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.cards, other.cards)
```

Now you should be able to use just `unsorted_list.sort()`.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you @Amadan. I'll write my own and compare it against yours. Cheers.