# Implement a list wrapper with overridden __cmp__ function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a new Python object as follows

```
class Mylist(list):
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if len(self)>len(other):
            return 1
        elif len(self)<len(other):
            return -1
        elif len(self)==len(other):
            return 0
```

my intend is, **when two `Mylist` objects are compared the object with large number of items should be higher**.

```
c=Mylist([4,5,6])
d=Mylist([1,2,3])
```

after running the above code, `c` and `d` are supposed to be equal(`c==d` <==**True**). But I am getting

```
>>> c==d
False
>>> c>d
True
>>>
```

they are being compared like the **list** object itself. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You `__cmp__` method is never called.

Comment: doesn't < operator(c<d) call __cmp__

Comment: It seems like `list` implements all of the rich comparison operators, i.e. `__lt__`, `__ge__`, `__eq__` etc., so those are called instead of `__cmp__`. Guess you'll have to overwrite all of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `list` implements all of the [rich comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), and `__cmp__` will [only be called if those are not defined](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__). Thus, it seems like you have to overwrite all of those:

```
class Mylist(list):

    def __lt__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) <  0
    def __le__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) <= 0
    def __eq__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) == 0
    def __ne__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) != 0
    def __gt__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) >  0
    def __ge__(self, other): return cmp(self, other) >= 0

    def __cmp__(self, other): return cmp(len(self), len(other))
```

BTW, it seems like `__cmp__` was removed entirely in Python 3. The above works in Python 2.x, but for compatibility you should probably rather do it like

```
    def __lt__(self, other): return len(self) < len(other)
```

Also see these two [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061283/lt-instead-of-cmp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276983/python-2-and-python-3-cmp). Note that while in Python 3 it would be enough to implement `__eq__` and `__lt__` and have Python infer the rest, this will not work in this case, since `list` already implements all of them, so you have to overwrite them all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement function `__eq__`.

```py
class Mylist(list):
  def __cmp__(self,other):
    if len(self)>len(other):
        return 1
    elif len(self)<len(other):
        return -1
    elif len(self)==len(other):
        return 0
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return len(self)==len(other)
```

**UPDATE:** (previous code does not work perfectly as explained in comments)

Although @tobias_k answer explains it better, you can do it via `__cmp__` function in Python 2 if you insist. You can *enable* it by removing other compare functions (le,lt,ge, ...):

```py
class Mylist(list):
  def __cmp__(self,other):
    if len(self)>len(other):
        return 1
    elif len(self)<len(other):
        return -1
    elif len(self)==len(other):
        return 0
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return len(self)==len(other)
  @property
  def __lt__(self, other): raise AttributeError()
  @property
  def __le__(self, other): raise AttributeError()
  @property
  def __ne__(self, other): raise AttributeError()
  @property
  def __gt__(self, other): raise AttributeError()
  @property
  def __ge__(self, other): raise AttributeError()
```

Comment: This fixes it for `==`, but not in general. `<`, `!=`, etc still work the way they do in `list`.

Comment: In Python 3, it seems mandatory to implement `__eq__` even when there is no base class--`__cmp__` returning 0 is not enough to make equality true, whereas it was in Python 2!

Comment: @JohnZwinck In Python3, `__cmp__` is no longer used at all. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276983/python-2-and-python-3-cmp)

Comment: @tobias_k: good to know, this will probably be of interest to the OP, should the code ever wind up on Python 3.