# What does the greater-than symbol mean in this piece of python code?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, syntax, notation

I am trying to implement a restricted boltzmann machine in C++. I am using this Python code as a guide:
https://github.com/echen/restricted-boltzmann-machines/blob/master/rbm.py

This is Line 37:

```
pos_hidden_states = pos_hidden_probs > np.random.rand(num_examples, self.num_hidden + 1)
```

pos_hidden_states and pos_hidden_probs are both 2D matrices, of type `vector<vector<double>>` in C++, and num_examples and num_hidden are both integers.

Could anyone explain what the greater-than symbol means here?

Comment: refer here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html#numpy.greater

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061283/lt-instead-of-cmp & https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not easy to translate `numpy` into C++, lot's of abstraction in `numpy`. Anyway, it's acting as a vectorized comparison, because `np.random.rand(...)` returns a `np.ndarray`, which if `pos_hidden_probs` is either a scalar or a `np.ndarray` it will behave in a vectorized (i.e. elementwise) manner:

```
>>> rand_array = np.random.rand(2, 2)
>>> rand_array
array([[ 0.1807726 ,  0.67617382],
       [ 0.84396805,  0.04450794]])
>>> 0.5 > rand_array
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

If `pos_hidden_probs` is some sort of `np.ndarray`, the behavior might be influenced by [*broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), a feature of numpy:

```
>>> np.array([0.5, 0.5]) > rand_array
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.array([0.5, .9]) > rand_array
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `>` operator works element-wise in NumPy, e.g.

```
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) > np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
```

gives you `np.array([[False,False],[True,True]])`

NumPy also does [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which gives meaning to comparison between arrays of different dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

The > is comparing the hidden prob (a float in this case) against each item in a 2d numpy array and returning a 2d array of boolean values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randn(3,2)array([[-0.74615339, -1.22667606],
       [ 0.22729787,  0.72070398],
       [-1.06876014,  0.06367189]])
>>> 5.  >  np.random.randn(3,2)
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to operator overloading, the `>` operator can do practically anything -- it simply invokes the `__gt__` special method on the object. But absent any other information, I would expect it to simply evaluate "greater than" and return a `bool` value.