# High low card game class comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively knew to Python, but I decided to create a high low card game using classes. Ive got the classes all setup and everything, but the only issue I'm having is when I try to see if the card from the `playerHand` is bigger or smaller than the one from `nextCard`. `playerHand` and `nextCard` are both tied to classes, and the error that I am getting is: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'NextCard'`.

There 100% is a better way to do this, but this is what I've got so far:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print ("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for suit in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for value in ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, value))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for n in range(len(self.cards)-1,0,-1):
            r = random.randint(0, n)
            self.cards[n], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[n]

    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def show(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

class NextCard(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nextcard = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.nextcard.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def show(self):
        for card1 in self.nextcard:
            card1.show()



deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

human = Person()
playerHand = human.draw(deck)

newcard = NextCard()
nextCard = newcard.draw(deck)



play = input("Do you want to play High/Low? Y or N? ")
while play.lower()== "y":
    card = playerHand
    print("The current card is: ", str(card.show()))
    guess = input("Guess H for high or L for low." )
    if guess.lower()=="h":
        if card > nextCard:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed correctly! The next card was ", card)
            play = input("Play again? Y or N? ")

        if card < nextCard:
            print("You lost! The next card was ", nextCard)
            play = input("Play again? Y or N? ")

    if guess.lower()=="l":
        if card > nextCard:
            print("You lost! The next card was ", nextCard)
            play = input("Play again? Y or N? ")

        if card < nextCard:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed correctly! The next card was ", nextCard)
else:
    print("The game is over.")
```

Any solutions or workarounds to the compare between classes problem would be much appreciated. This was coded in python 3.

Comment: Do your classes have the value of the card? Then you could do `if card.value > nextcard.value` (or through a getter-function etc.) You can also make your classes comparable, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061283/lt-instead-of-cmp)

Comment: i got a deck class which has all of the card suits and values in it but also a separate card class which just combines the two variables from the deck class

Comment: I think you need to share more information then. It is impossible to help you, if we can't reproduce your problem. Try creating a minimal reproducible code-snippet. E.g. your problem can be boiled down to `card < nextCard` throwing the exception you mention.

Comment: Your question is about using classes and there is not one class here... How can we help? Please provide a [mre]. At least show what are `playerHand` and `nextCard`. BTW, you should follow PEP-8's `names_with_under_scores` rather than the Java-like `CamelCase`. So it should be `player_hand` and `next_card`

Comment: From the error message `playerHand` must be an instance of class `Person`, so the statement `card = playerHand` makes no sense. It's impossible to help you further without seeimg the class definitions (and possibly more of the other logic in your program).

Comment: ok i pasted the whole file in the question above. feel free to rip it to shreds and tell me how i screwed up. the NextCard and Person class are the same but output different cards so I figured that it could be used as a 'next card' varaible for the program to compare it to the card in the playerHand. thanks

Comment: `human.draw(deck)` returns `self` which is a `Person`, so `playerhand` is of type `Person`. You should ensure that `card` and `nextCard` are both of type `Card`. Then you can compare them with `card.value > nextCard.value`. I would consider not having a class for `NextCard` - can't you store the next card by calling `deck.drawCard()`? Or if you need a way to represent used cards, I would call it e.g. `Pile` and implement the logic of persisting cards there.

Answer (score 0):

Are these playerHand and nextCard classes ?

To compare two classes with < operator you need to do operator overloading.

But that is advance level python

> In here the fault is maybe that  you are not creating object of classes

you are only aliasing the class playerHand

to make a object of it do

```
card = playerHand()
```

But it won't fix the problem (probably)

please give me a inner look of the class (edit your question in brief)

Comment: i pasted the project above.

Answer (score 0):

**Now consider how the big boys do it**

> add a < and > operator over-loader in your classes that you are trying to compare

for < add a `__lt__()` method in your class

for > add a `__gt__()` method in your class

those `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` will do the overloading of operator

** (overloading means programming operators for custom use) **

> In your code you need to add them in **class Card** and **class Person**

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __gt__(self, comparing_card):
        # result is gonna be a boolean value
        # the ace jack qween king will need some comparing basis
        # work on it
        result = self.value > comparing_card.value
        return result

    def __lt__(self, comparing_card):
        result = self.value < comparing_card.value
        return result

    def show(self):
        print ("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))
```

and another class

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def __gt__(self, comparing_obj):
        # result is gonna be a boolean value
        result = self.hand[-1] > comparing_obj.nextcard[-1]
        return result

     def __lt__(self, comparing_obj):
        # result is gonna be a boolean value
        result = self.hand[-1] < comparing_obj.nextcard[-1]
        return result

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def show(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
```

And this is the last fragment where you compare your class

```
    # here we need oparator overloading
    # this initially means '> sign' will call card.__gt__(nextCard)
    # > sign will call card's ___gt__ method and pass nextCard as a parameter
    # ___gt__(nextCard) returns a boolean value that we feed to the if statement down there

    if card > nextCard:
        # in here the print shows the class node
        print("Congratulations! You guessed correctly! The next card was ", card)
        #  change card to card.show()
        play = input("Play again? Y or N? ")
```

well this is a very deep topic (if its hard to comprehend) and intermediate python stuff. you can try some online stuff to know about it briefly.

try this geeks for geeks tutorial:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/