# Python using methods from other classes

Tags: python, class, methods

If I have two classes, and one of them has a function that I want to use in my other class, what do I use so that I don't have to rewrite my function?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are two options:

- instanciate an object in your class, then call the desired method on it
- use [@classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) to turn a function into a class method

Example:

```
class A(object):
    def a1(self):
        """ This is an instance method. """
        print "Hello from an instance of A"

    @classmethod
    def a2(cls):
        """ This a classmethod. """
        print "Hello from class A"

class B(object):
    def b1(self):
        print A().a1() # => prints 'Hello from an instance of A'
        print A.a2() # => 'Hello from class A'
```

Or use inheritance, if appropriate:

```
class A(object):
    def a1(self):
        print "Hello from Superclass"

class B(A):
    pass

B().a1() # => prints 'Hello from Superclass'
```

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance here. This is single inheritance, although it is possible that you are thinking of hierarchical inheritance.

Comment: @Nikwin, +1 as I was just going to say that.

Comment: of course, i meant just inheritance. thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 31):

There are several approaches:

- Inheritance
- Delegation
- Super-sneaky delegation

The following examples use each for sharing a function that prints a member.

**Inheritance**

```
class Common(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def sharedMethod(self):
        print self.x

class Alpha(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        Common.__init__(self,"Alpha")

class Bravo(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        Common.__init__(self,"Bravo")
```

**Delegation**

```
class Common(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def sharedMethod(self):
        print self.x

class Alpha(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.common = Common("Alpha")
    def sharedMethod(self):
         self.common.sharedMethod()

class Bravo(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.common = Common("Bravo")
    def sharedMethod(self):
         self.common.sharedMethod()
```

**Super-sneaky Delegation**
This solution is based off of the fact that there is nothing special about Python member functions; you can use any function or callable object so long as the first parameter is interpreted as the instance of the class.

```
def commonPrint(self):
    print self.x

class Alpha(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "Alpha"
    sharedMethod = commonPrint

class Bravo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "Bravo"
    sharedMethod = commonPrint
```

Or, a similarly sneaky way of achieving delegation is to use a callable object:

```
class Printable(object):
   def __init__(self,x):
       self.x = x
   def __call__(self):
       print self.x

class Alpha(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.sharedMethod = Printable("Alpha")

class Bravo(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.sharedMethod = Printable("Bravo")
```

Comment: What's the use case for your last example? I mean, if you call `Alpha().sharedMethod()` you get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Is there an approach that is more pythonic than the other?

Answer (score 7):

you create a class from which both classes inherit.

There is multiple inheritance, so if they already have a parent it's not a problem.

```
class master ():
    def stuff (self):
        pass

class first (master):
    pass


class second (master):
    pass


ichi=first()
ni=second()

ichi.stuff()
ni.stuff()
```

Comment: a.k.a. [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714)?