# How to use a method in a class from another class that inherits from yet another class python

Tags: python, class

I have 3 classes :

```
class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        pass

class CentralCorridor(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        pass

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, start_game): 
        pass
```

And the class map is initiated like this :

```
a_map = map('central_corridor')
```

It means that there is a map(obviously not graphical like a maze let's suppose) in which the first scene of the game(the game is like zork) is central corridor.

So I want to use the enter method of the class CentralCorridor in  the map class but I am confused by the fact that the class CnetralCorridor itself inherits from the class Scene. I don't know how can I use the delegation method as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797332/2572773

Answer (score 1):

1) It's a good practice for Python classes to start with an uppercase letter.
   Furthermore, the name **map** is a built-in python function.

2) what's wrong with passing a Scene instance on your map class?

```
class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
    def enter(self):
        self.scene.enter()

a_map = Map(CentralCorridor())
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this code help:

```
class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print 'Scene Object'

class CentralCorridor(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print 'CentralCorridor object'

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, start_game):
        self.start_game = start_game
        if self.start_game == 'central_corridor':
            whatever = CentralCorridor().enter()

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
```

You should not use map, but Map instead, because map() is a build-in function

Comment: I don't understand why you have to do a string comparison in order to instantiate the proper object(in this case CentralCorridor). Unless you're trying to be as close to what the OP asked, which is quite broken anyway.

Comment: Well, yes I am trying to be close. Since I have no idea, why you call an object with a string and ask for a method. I guess depending on the string you will choose a method to call. That is why.

Comment: OK you were trying to be close to the original question. Although I didn't get the rest of what you said. You don't choose a *method* depending on the string. You choose a *Class*. The method is always *enter*, as far as I can see. That's why I don't get the string comparison.

Comment: Yes, you choose a class, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should rename your map class, since `map` is a builtin function you'll shadow here.

To answer your question: you can call CentralCorridor.enter(self) to explicitly call CentralCorridor's enter method on the current instance (which does not have to *be* a CentralCorridor instance).

Comment: so i can directly right CentralCorridor.enter and set it to a variable in Map class??

Comment: what you suggest seems like a really bad idea. But maybe I am misunderstanding something. Could you provide an actual example? Because this is more of a comment than an answer, as it currently stands.