# Use class A method in class B, where B overwrites this method

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am aware of this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797139/python-using-methods-from-other-classes)**. Mine is similar, but not the same, because I overwrite said method. And I cannot use `@staticmethod` because I will need to use it on `self` as well in other functions of the class.

I have `class Player` and `class Dealer`. In `Player` I define a method called `print_cards`. In class `Dealer` I overwrite this method. How can I get a Dealer instance to use the `Player`'s `print_cards` method and not its own?

```
class Player():
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Player\'s class.')

class Dealer(Player):
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Dealer\'s class.')

p = Player()
d = Dealer()

p.print_cards()
d.print_cards()

d.Player.print_cards()  # this is what I am thinking, but it is not valid python

>>> I am in Player's class.
>>> I am in Dealer's class.
```

Comment: Try `Player.print_cards(d)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this? Without super() you don't exactly override the parent method, just redefine it. (Not sure though, I try to avoid inheritance if I can).

```
class Player():
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Player\'s class.')

class Dealer(Player):
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Dealer\'s class.')
    def print_player(self):
        super().print_cards()

p = Player()
d = Dealer()

p.print_cards()
d.print_cards()
d.print_player()
```

Output is:

```
I am in Player's class.
I am in Dealer's class.
I am in Player's class.
```

Although specified as a Python 3 question, here's how you do it in Python 2

```
class Player(object):
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Player\'s class.')

class Dealer(Player):
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Dealer\'s class.')
    def print_player(self):
        super(Dealer, self).print_cards()
```

`super` works in different ways for python 2 and 3. Specifically notice the difference in `def` statement of `Player` class:

```
 class Player(object):
```

which is known as a "new-style" class in Python2. By default all classes in Python 3 are new-style classes if I remember correctly. Additionally notice that `super` requires a type of class of which you're looking for a parent, and an `self` which is an bound object, a child of the parent class.

Comment: You should highlight the Python 2/3 differences here.

Comment: @Mr.F Question specified Python3. I've added the differences, is this correct? (Like I said, I try to avoid inheritance)

Comment: If `Player.print_cards()` take import more than just `self` do I have to specify them in my `Super.print_cards()`?

Comment: @Vader If by import you mean parameters then yes of course you do. It behaves exactly the same as if you'd have an instance.method(args/kwargs) there.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a class's instance method with another self. E.g.:

```
class Player():
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Player\'s class.')

class Dealer(Player):
    def print_cards(self):
        print('I am in Dealer\'s class.')

p = Player()
d = Dealer()

p.print_cards()
d.print_cards()

Player.print_cards(d)  # Not an instance
```

Output:

```
I am in Player's class
I am in Dealer's class
I am in Player's class
```

This is not very useful in this circumstance. Another example:

```
class Being:
    def __init__(self):
        self.saying = "Patience is a virtue."
        self.home = "Earth"

    def say_virtue(self):
        print(self.saying)

    def say_home(self):
        print(self.home)

class Yoda:
    def __init__(self):
        self.saying = "Is patience virtue a."
        self.home = "Far galaxy away far."

    def say_virtue(self):
        print("Mean you 'Virtue say'?")

yoda = Yoda()
being = Being()

being.say_virtue()  # Says beings virtue
yoda.say_virtue()   # Says yodas virtue
Being.say_virtue(yoda)   # says Beings virtue with yodas `self.virtue`
# And as a side note:
print(yoda.say_home == being.say_home)  # Instances
print(Yoda.say_home == Being.say_home)  # Classes

## Prints:
Patience is a virtue.
Mean you 'Virtue say'?
Is patience virtue a.
False
True
```

Comment: I will use `Player.print_cards(d)` since I will only need to do it once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Often one says that a method in superclass can be called with `super().method(self)`, which is not quite the whole truth.

The `super` is often not the correct thing to do, in that it does not call the method in superclass, but *the method that is in the next type in the current object's types method resolution order.* In case of multiple inheritance it can call a method in a class that you did not anticipate:

```
class A(object):
    def say(self):
        print("I am A, just sayin'")

class B(A):
    def say(self):
        print("This is B, I let A speak for me")
        super().say()
```

`B.say()` calls `A.say()`, right?

Wrong, because we have also:

```
class C(A):
    def say(self):
        print("Hey it is me C")

class D(B, C):
    pass
```

Now we create an instance of `D`, and invoke `say()` on it:

```
D().say()
```

The output is:

```
This is B, I let A speak for me
Hey it is me C
```

That is, `super()` delegated the execution from `B.say` to the class `C` that the `B` is not aware at all, and `B` is neither a subclass nor superclass of `C`. The `super()` is a misnomer; it should really be called `next_type` or something. Thus in case you know what class to deliver to, do not use `super` but call the method explicitly:

```
class B(A):
    def say(self):
        print("This is B, I let A speak for me")
        A.say(self)
```