# How to use method of one class to another class in different files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am quite new to python, so pardon me for basic question. I tried google for past few days but could not make it in my program.

Can anyone show me a good example how can I use method from One class to another in python and what is significance of `__init__` while defining class.

I am using python2.7

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do

Comment: Read This Too  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797139/python-using-methods-from-other-classes

Comment: Read this too once you go through the basics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Answer (score 4):

To use a method defined in one class inside of another class, you have several options:

1. Create an instance of B from within one of A's methods, then call B's method:

   ```
   class A:
       def methodInA():
           b = B()
           b.methodInB()
   ```
2. If appropriate, use the concept of **inheritance** (one of the defining concepts of object-oriented design) to create a subclass of the original class whose method(s) you wish to use:

   ```
   class B(A):
       ...
   ```

`__init__()` is a class *initializer*. Whenever you instantiate an object you are invoking `__init__()` whether or not it is explicitly defined. It's main purpose is to initialize class data members:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def printName(self):
        print self.name

c = C("George")
c.printName() # outputs George
```

With `__init__()` defined, in particular with the additional argument `name` in this example, you are able to differentiate between would-be generically *constructed* instances by allowing for different initial states from instance to instance.

Comment: I want to do like two classes are in different python files.

Comment: I believe the `import` keyword is what you are looking for. Once you've imported the file containing one of the classes into the other file the above still applies.

Comment: so it will be like 
"from fileA.py import classA; " Correct??

Comment: `from fileA import ClassA` is fine

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues here:

First: Using method of class A in class B, both classes in different files

```
class A:
    def methodOfA(self):
        print "method Of A"
```

let the above class be in file a.py Now the class B is supposed to be in b.py. Both a.py and b.py are assumed to be on the same level or in the same location. Then b.py would look like:

```
import a
class B:
    def methodOfB(self):
        print "Method of B"
        a.A().methodOfA()
```

You can also do this by inherting A in B

```
import a
class B(a.A):
    def methodOfB(self):
        print "Method of B"
        self.methodOfA()
```

there are several other ways to use A in B. I will leave it to you to explore.

Now to your second question. The use of `__init__` in a class. `__init__` is not a constructor, as popularly believed and explained above. It is, as the name suggests, an initialization function. It is called only after the object has already been constructed and it is implicitly passed the object instance as the first argument, as signified by *self* in its argument list.

The actual constructor in python is called `__new__`, which does not need a object to call it. This is actually a specialized **Static method**, which receives the class instance as the first argument. `__new__` is exposed for overwriting only if the class inherits form the **object** base class of python

Whatever other arguments are passed while creating an object of a class, first go to `__new__` and then are passed with the object instance to the `__init__`, if it accepts them.

Comment: Updated constructor to initializer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `init` function is what is called a constructor function. When you create an instance of a class `object = myClass()`, `init` is the function that is automatically called. i.e.

That being said, to call a function from one class to another, you need to call an instance of the second class inside the first one, or vice versa. for eg.

```
class One():
    def func(self):
        #does sometthing here

class Two():
    def __init__(self):
        self.anotherClass = One()
        #Now you can access the functions of the first class by using anotherClass followed by dot operator
        self.anotherClass.func()

#When you call the main class. This is the time the __init__ function is automatically called

mainClass = Two()
```

Another way to access from another class is the use of [oop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) concept called Inheritance.

```
class One():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class One Called')
    def func(self):
        print('func1 Called')

class Two(One):
    def __init__(self):
        One.__init__(self,) #This basically creates One's instance
        print('Main Called')

c= Two()
c.func()
```

The output for this is:

> Class One Called
>   Main Called
>   func1 Called