# Can not call a function to a class from other classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter, self

I am new in Python classes and trying to write an interface for a scientific code via Tkinter. But I can not call a function (which is in another class and opens a different frame) from a class or function. I have been searching for more than 2 days but could not find an answer to my case. If you explain like explaining a child I would be very happy since I don't know much technical details.

My code structure is like:

```
class first_class(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                 ....
        def WhateverFunction():
           "do sth"
class second_class(tk.Tk):

   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
               .....
       **I want to use "WhateverFunction" here** 
               .....
```

so basically, I can not access that function from another class.

The searches I found online like [Python using methods from other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797139/python-using-methods-from-other-classes) method. Bu This did not solve my problem. It is maybe because I am working with different Tkinter frames. I do not now... Thanks already, cheers!

Comment: you need to inherit from the first class you have made if you want to use that function. `class second_class(first_class):` or call the class method from within `first_class().WhateverFunction()`

Comment: Does `WhateverFunction` need to be a method of `first_class` at all ? NB : the way your snippet is indented, `WhateverFunction` is actually defined within `first_class.__init__` and as such is only accessible within `first_class.__init__`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ahh... Had put that down to a copy/paste or indentation error. But yes, that would change any possible answers somewhat

Comment: You cannot have two instances of `tk.Tk` (or two instances of something that inherits from `tk.Tk`). Why must you have two classes that each inherit from `tk.Tk`?

Comment: @BryanOakley That is the second part of the comment, but yes "you need to..." is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you defined the function `WhateverFunction` as a local function within `__init__`. So it can't be seen from other sections of your code and it's impossible to be called.

Instead you can implement your function as a method, for example. It would look like this:

```
class first_class(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
             ....
    def WhateverFunction(self):
       "do sth"
```

Now the function can be called everywhere as a method of an instance of `first_class`:

```
first_class_instance = first_class()
first_class_instance.WhateverFunction()
```

Comment: Well no - leaving aside the lack of `self`, it'd still be callable via `first_class.WhateverFunction()`... it's not impossible to be called.

Comment: @JonClements Look at the OP's code. `WhateverFunction` is local within `__init__`, so it can't be called, because it doesn't exist outside.

Comment: Yes... Just noticed... See my comment on the Q to Bruno. If it's deliberate then you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the exact same question on here a while back with no response. Basically, you can't do it. `WhateverFunction` only exists within the scope of `__init__`, which itself can **only** be *called* from `second_class`. This is done with the method described in the 'using methods from other classes' question you linked to, but it is useless for doing what you want to do because you may only get an *output* from `__init__`, and hence you can't access any functions defined within that function.

To work around this, why not define `WhateverFunction` globally and then call it as usual, or declare it outside of the `__init__` function but still within `first_class`?

Answer (score -1):

Just create an instance of that class, and call the method if the second_class instance should be composed of the first one.

```
def second_class(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        first_object = first_class().WhateverFunction()
```

Now a better approach would be to inherit `second_class` from the first one instead, and calling the method considering both classes have same parent, provided inheritance makes sense.

```
def second_class(first_class):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super(second_class, self).__init__(parent, controller)

        self.WhateverFunction()
```

Note:- please try to follow certain conventions of Python like naming classes with camel case, and methods/functions with snake case.

Comment: inheritance is very probably not a "better approach"... Composition/delegation is usually a better choice, and actually plain functions or utility classes defined outside GUI classes are also a good way to share code without introducing undue dependencies.

Comment: What if the he's using the above class as just a mixin. I agree that's composition is often better than inheritance, but there are places where inheritance would make more sense.

Comment: "there are places" indeed - I mean, there are _a few_ places where inheritance is the right solution. Only a few... Now we don't really have enough context to really say what's the "best" solution would be here since we don't know what `WhateverFunction()` does nor even if it really belongs in `first_class` to start with ;)

Comment: I agree we don't have enough knowledge to derive any adequate conclusion, but considering both of the classes are inheriting from `tk.Tk`, it's an educated guess that inheritance would be a better approach.

Comment: The fact that two classes A and B have the same parent class P doesn't imply that A is a B in any way, specially when it comes to GUI or ORM classes.

Comment: That's why I had specially written that "provided inheritance makes sense". In the case you mentioned, it wouldn't.