# How to call methods of other classes in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Config_A(test.Case):
    def insert(self, protocol_id):
        ...
        ...


class Config_B(test.Case):
    ...
    ....
    ....

    def test_somecase(self):
        self.insert(10)
```

Here def insert() is a common method, which is required by multiple classes. From class Config_B, its not able to access the definition of insert() defined in Config_A.
One solution is that, define it in Config_B and make use of. But it's a duplication of code. How can we do this without writing duplicate code?

Comment: How familiar are you with inheritance?

Comment: You can use `inheritance`, and you'll be able to access  methods of parent class. In your case it'd be, `class config_B(Config_A, test.Case):`.

Comment: see this if it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797139/python-using-methods-from-other-classes

Answer (score 1):

```
class Config_A():
    def insert(self, protocol_id):
        print 'protocol_id=',protocol_id

class Config_B(Config_A):
    def test_somecase(self):
        Config_A().insert(10)

def main():
    obj = Config_B()
    obj.test_somecase()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This one worked.

Comment: `Config_A().insert(10)` can be replaced by `self.insert(10)`. Otherwise, you create a temporary instance that is immediately destroyed.