# What is the difference between Abstract classes and Mixins in Python django

Tags: python, django, oop

Can anyone please tell what is the difference between Abstract class and Mixin in Django.
I mean if we are to inherit some methods from base class why there is separate terminology like mixins if that is just a class.

What is diff between baseclass and mixins

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263417/django-abstract-models-vs-simple-python-mixins-vs-python-abcs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python (and Django), **mixin** is a type of multiple inheritance. I tend to think of them
as "specilist" classes that adds a particular functionality to the class that
inheritates it (along with other classes). They aren't really meant to stand on
their own.

Example with Django's `SingleObjectMixin`,

```
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from books.models import Author

class RecordInterest(View, SingleObjectMixin):
    """Records the current user's interest in an author."""
    model = Author

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        # Look up the author we're interested in.
        self.object = self.get_object()
        # Actually record interest somehow here!

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('author-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))
```

The added [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) will enable you to look up the `author` with just [`self.get_objects()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object).

---

An abstract class in Python looks like this:

```
class Base(object):
    # This is an abstract class

    # This is the method child classes need to implement
    def implement_me(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("told you so!")
```

In languages like Java, there is an `Interface` contract which is an
*interface*. However, Python doesn't have such and the *closest* thing you can
get is an abstract class (you can also read on [abc](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). This is mainly because Python utlizes [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python) which kind of removes the need for interfaces. Abstract class enables polymorphism just like interfaces do.