# Does South handle model mixins?

Tags: django, django-south, mixins

I've created a mixin and inherited from it in some models. The problem is when I create a schema migration, the mixin's fields are there.

```
class MyMixin(object):
    a_field = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    another_field = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyModel(models.Model, myMixin):
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is South creating a table for MyMixin? If so it could be an indentation problem with the Meta information. If your indentation is correct and you mean South is adding the fields to `MyModel` then it's working as expected. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance Model inheritance option 1.

Comment: fix your indentation of `class Meta:` in `class MyMixin`

Comment: indentation problem fixed (this was just a problem in my post, my actual code had the correct indentation for Meta)

Answer (score 5):

Seem to have got it working using the following

```
class MyMixin(models.Model):
    a_field = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    another_field = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyModel(myMixin, models.Model):
    ...
```

The changes are:

- MyMixin inherits Model rather than object (despite many discussions around the place saying that mixins for django should inherit object rather than Model)
- the order of inheritance for MyModel - the mixin has to come first