# Abstract model with dynamic fields

Tags: django, django-orm

I am wondering since ages how to achieve the following:

I have an abstract class wrapping several attributes shared by multiple models. But not every model needs every attribute in exactly the same way.

Here is an example: `MyModelA` and `MyModelB` both have two fields: `value_1` and `value_2`. But while `MyModelA` needs them to be required/not nullable, they can be nullable for `MyModelB`.

```
class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    value_1 = models.IntegerField()
    value_2 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

What I tried:

1. Not deriving `MyAbstractModel` from `models.Model` but from `object` like a regular mixin
2. Setting a class attribute which is overwritten in the child classes to determine the nullable-state. It always takes the definition from `MyAbstractModel`.
3. Using a class attribute but not set it in the `MyAbstractModel`. Then the `makemigrations` command fails because of the undefined variable.
4. Cry

Being DRY is such an important paradigm in django, I really wonder that there is nothing on this topic in the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, but, I wouldn't include fields that aren't ***"identical"*** in the base model

Comment: think of using `Model mixins` https://www.ianlewis.org/en/mixins-and-python

Comment: @cizario Wont work for model fields! They are not detected and therefore never are persisted in the database :(

Comment: @JPG Sorry, didnt get your point. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Ron can you explain that ? mixins are simply python classes, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817237/12368419, i used model mixins in my projects without any problems (migrations are created as it should be, and the database is created)

Comment: That is `value_1 = models.IntegerField()` is not same as `value_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)` (in Django as well as in DB). So, I would redefine them in my subclasses as per my requiremernt

Comment: @cizario Thats interesting, found some articles in the net describing exactly my behavior! Just give it a shot, maybe it worked on older django versions?

Comment: @JPG True, but still not DRY. Thats why I asked the question :(

Comment: Imho, you dont have to think about dry here

Comment: it seems this way :)