# In Python 3, best Pythonic way to set base class method to run once only

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm currently trying to log the full class name and method that is currently running.

In the following rough code, I have a class attribute in Base that tracks whether or not the logging handler has been added. Without it, I get one message for each time the Base class is inherited, which makes perfect sense. e.g. without it I get this output:

```
1688489421.224986 DEBUG Base.TestClassA.testmethod1 |debug message from test class A|
1688489421.225088  INFO Base.TestClassB.testmethod2 |info message from test class B|
1688489421.225088  INFO Base.TestClassB.testmethod2 |info message from test class B|
1688489421.225162 ERROR Base.TestClassC.another_method |error message from test class C|
1688489421.225162 ERROR Base.TestClassC.another_method |error message from test class C|
1688489421.225162 ERROR Base.TestClassC.another_method |error message from test class C|
```

A test at the end of the `__init__` method then only calls `self.__logger.addHandler(console_handler)` once. With the check, the correct output is seen:

```
1688490430.369992 DEBUG Base.TestClassA.testmethod1 |debug message from test class A|
1688490430.370093  INFO Base.TestClassB.testmethod2 |info message from test class B|
1688490430.370155 ERROR Base.TestClassC.another_method |error message from test class C|
```

But is that the right way to do it? It feels a little fragile, but I'm still very much a beginner so I don't have the experience to really tell.

What's the correct Pythonic way to only call `self.__logger.addHandler(console_handler)` once?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging


# Cargo culted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731615/2988388
class MetaBase(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # Explicit name mangling
        logger_attribute_name = "_" + cls.__name__ + "__logger"

        # Logger name derived accounting for inheritance for the bonus marks
        logger_name = ".".join([c.__name__ for c in cls.mro()[-2::-1]])

        setattr(cls, logger_attribute_name, logging.getLogger(logger_name))


class Base(metaclass=MetaBase):
    log_handler_added = False

    def __init__(self):
        log_formatter = logging.Formatter(
            "{created:<f} {levelname:>5s} {name}.{funcName:>8s} |{message}|",
            style="{",
        )
        loglevel = "DEBUG"

        # turn the "info", "debug" etc env var value into a number
        # that sets the logging level of detail
        numeric_level = getattr(logging, loglevel.upper(), None)
        if not isinstance(numeric_level, int):
            raise ValueError("Invalid log level: %s" % loglevel)

        # Just log to stdout/stderr
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
        self.__logger.setLevel(numeric_level)

        # use the class attribute to only add the handler once,
        # otherwise you get a log message for each time Base
        # has been inherited
        # https://stackoverflow.com/q/36320514/2988388
        if not Base.log_handler_added:
            self.__logger.addHandler(console_handler)
            Base.log_handler_added = True


class TestClassA(Base):
    def testmethod1(self):
        self.__logger.debug("debug message from test class A")


class TestClassB(Base):
    def testmethod2(self):
        self.__logger.info("info message from test class B")


class TestClassC(Base):
    def another_method(self):
        self.__logger.error("error message from test class C")


a = TestClassA()
a.testmethod1()

b = TestClassB()
b.testmethod2()

p = TestClassC()
p.another_method()
```

And as a bonus question, is it possible to use this metaclass+inheritance to log messages in `__main__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems over-complex. I would use a simple mixin and a formatter set on the root logger of the application. It can be the responsibility of main to initialize the root logger.

Mixin:

```
class LoggingMixin:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def log(cls):
        return logging.getLogger(cls.__name__)
```

Classes:

```
class TestClassA(LoggingMixin):
    def testmethod1(self):
        self.log.debug("debug message from test class A")


class TestClassB(LoggingMixin):
    def testmethod2(self):
        self.log.info("info message from test class B")


class TestClassC(LoggingMixin):
    def another_method(self):
        self.log.error("error message from test class C")
```

Setup:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="{created:<f} {levelname:>5s} {name}.{funcName:>8s} |{message}|",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        style="{",
    )

    a = TestClassA()
    a.testmethod1()

    b = TestClassB()
    b.testmethod2()

    p = TestClassC()
    p.another_method()
```

Output:

```
1688494741.449282 DEBUG TestClassA.testmethod1 |debug message from test class A|
1688494741.449282  INFO TestClassB.testmethod2 |info message from test class B|
1688494741.450281 ERROR TestClassC.another_method |error message from test class C|
```

Comment: Astonishing! That's so much simpler than the other solutions I've seen. I will give this a try and mark you as the correct answer as soon as I can. Huge thank you, I can see that I have a lot, a whole enormous amount, more to learn about Python.

Comment: @acjca2 Glad to have helped! Doing it this way also has the advantage of sharing a single log format for the entire application. It will even make the formatting consistent from dependencies you pip install if they also output to the logging module.