# Subclasses vs Mixins in Python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain the difference between Subclasses vs Mixins as I'm still unable to find s good resource or answer to this question.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful -- According to the answer there, a mixin isn't meant to stand on it's own.

Comment: Wow -- It looks like we're all equally adept at using Google :-P

Comment: Actually I'm 2 seconds more adept than David and 13 seconds more adept than you, give me some credit :p

Comment: Though I do bow down to your google searching skills :0) the previous thread does not attempt to explain the differences between the 2.