# (ArcGIS) Create new function for Arcpy

Tags: python, toolbox, arcpy

As a result for my graduation paper I am trying to create a new toolbox for ArcGIS using Python scripting. The problem is I am stuck with my code because none of the existing functions in Arcpy does what I need to do. So my question is, is it possible to create a new function in Arcpy or this is restricted to ESRI developers?

Another way to solve this problem would be implement some changes in the tool Cost Distance from Spatial Analyst. So my other question is, do I have access to the coding of the native tools from ArcGIS? And if I have, can I change it to achieve my goal? Or this is also restricted?

Thanks,

Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create your own functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) using Python and the Python arcpy site-package.  All of ESRI's tools are proprietary, and therefore, most have restricted access.  You can check to see if you can edit the tools in the ArcToolbox.  For example, you can see the Cost Distance tool is restricted:

[image]

While the Spline with Barriers tool can be edited by right-clicking on the script tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own python toolbox for ArcPy following this help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001500000022000000

also checkout the environment variables for your existing tool, it might have some options that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year late, but I would like to add a couple ideas to what has been posted for folks like me who are searching for python toolbox help.

For educational purposes, begin by creating a model in Model Builder. This is one way to use ESRI's proprietary tools in new ways. Decide what you want to do and look at ESRI's presence on GitHub. The developers there have a lot of open-source tools ready to use in ArcMap. Here is one such repository: [GeospatialPython](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp)

Side note, contributing to a repository is a great resume builder.

After creating your working model builder, right click on it in ArcCatalog and select 'export as Python script'. Open the script in your favorite IDE and begin cleaning it up!

Now that you have a python script, it is ready to become a python toolbox. Use gDexter42's link and get to work on that.

My team has some interesting uses for python toolboxes and I am currently creating my very first one.

1. We use a runner scripts to debug our software. (hard-coded parameters)
2. We use inheritance for functions that we use over and over again (class BaseToolboxMixin(object):) [Stack Exchange Article on Mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)
3. Most importantly, we have created our own python module around the tool.
4. The .pyt file we made simply imports arcpy, the module we created, executes the module from a list we created in our 'toolbox_loader.py' file, and has a class that calls the **init** file that created the module in the first place. >20 lines of code.
5. As our team creates more tools for the module/python toolbox, we will add them to the list. They will appear inside our toolbox alongside all the ESRI tools. "Seamless integration" was thrown around a lot at the Dev Summit this year.

ESRI is encouraging creativity and open-source usage (check out esri leaflet). I wouldn't constrain my thinking because ESRI's tools are proprietary.

All of this functionality began as a model in ArcMap. Not everyone is going to need to create their own module - complete overkill for most tasks - but it is good to know that the ceiling for Python functionality is high. I am not an experienced developer, but I was able to go from nothing to a functional python toolbox in about 25 man-hours of work. Someone who knows their stuff could do it in a morning.