# On-demand creation of member methods using __getattr__()

Tags: python, class, oop, member, getattr

Given a class `MyClass(object)`, how can I programmatically define class member methods using some template and the `MyClass.__getattr__` mechanism?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, defaultmembers, members):
        # defaultmembers is a list
        # members is a dict
        self._defaultmembers = defaultmembers
        self._members = members

    # some magic spell creating a member function factory

    def __getattr__(self):
        # some more magic

def f_MemberB():
    pass

C = MyClass(defaultmembers=["MemberA"], members=dict(MemberB=f_MemberB)
C.MemberA()  # should be a valid statement
C.MemberB()  # should also be a valid statement
C.MemberC()  # should raise an AttributeError
```

`C.MemberA` should be a method automatically created from some template mechanism inside the class, and `C.MemberB` should be the function `f_MemberB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to redefine `__getattr__` (and in fact you generally should never do that). Python is a [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) language. This means you can simply assign values to names in a class at any time (even dynamically at runtime) and they will now exist.

So, in your case, you can simply do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, defaultmembers, members):
        # defaultmembers is a list
        # members is a dict
        for func in defaultmembers:
            setattr(self, func.__name__, func)
        for name, func in members.items():
            setattr(self, name, func)
```

Note that this will not actually *bind* the method to the class (it will not get *self* as its first argument). If that is what you want,  you need to use the [MethodType](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#module-types) function from `types`, like so:

```
from types import MethodType

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, defaultmembers, members):
        # defaultmembers is a list
        # members is a dict
        for func in defaultmembers:
            name =  func.__name__
            setattr(self, name , func)
            setattr(self, name , MethodType(getattr(self, name), self))
        for name, func in members.items():
            setattr(self, name, func)
            setattr(self, name , MethodType(getattr(self, name), self))
```

Example:

```
def def_member(self):
    return 1

def key_member(self):
    return 2

>>> test = MyClass([def_member], {'named_method':key_member})
>>> test.def_member()
1
>>> test.named_method()
2
```

You can also make the init method slightly less awkward by using `*args` and `**kwargs`, so that the example would just be `test = MyClass(def_member, named_member = key_member)` if you know there won't be any other arguments to the constructor of this class.

Obviously I've left out the template creation bit for the `defaultmembers`, since I've used passing a function, rather than simply a name, as the argument. But you should be able to see how you would expand that example to suit your needs, as the template creation part is a bit out of the scope of the original question, which is how to dynamically bind methods to classes.

An important note: This only affects **the single instance of `MyClass`**. Please alter the question if you want to affect all instances. Though I would think using [mixin class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) would be better in that case.