# Django TemplateResponseMixin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, mixins

I am new to Django and trying to get my head around mixins with class based views. As per my understanding, mixins are classes containing a combination of methods from other classes(similar to multiple inheritance).

I am following the official documentation and searched for questions on SO, but did not understand why `TemplateResponseMixin` is a *mixin* per se. What methods of different classes are being injected into the `TemplateResponseMixin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TemplateResponseMixin -  **A mixin that can be used to render a template.**

It has two methods -

render_to_response() and get_template_names()

For more info refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin)

Answer (score 10):

You can think of `mixins` as *partial* classes which are used to enrich another class by providing extra functionality. However, mixins itself do not contain enough information in order to constitute a complete class but they offer new features to classes they are added into.

In your case, `TemplateResponseMixin` alone can't be considered as a  `View` class because it has lack of many crucial methods like `get`, `post` or `dispatch` that will have us identify it as an actual view.

However, together with the help of `BaseView` (or `View`) class, it creates another form of view named `TemplateView` and gives that the ability of rendering a `template` via `render_to_response` method unlike normal view.

A good metaphor would be the human body. It is composed of different layers, all of them are specialized in doing something but, the bottom line 
is that, they all need some kind of skeletal system first in order to be kept together and stay meaningful. Thus, in this scenario, *human skeleton* (`View`) would be considered as the "thing" that makes entire system meaningful and we would wrap that [skeleton](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3/h3px/skeleton.gif) up with a *skin* (`TemplateResponseMixin`) in order to make it look like more [human](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3/h3px/walkingdead.gif).

Re-interpreting this concept using Django's class-based view approach, we get;

```
class View(BaseView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == GET:
            self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == POST:
            self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

As you see, view has no idea whether it defines `get()` method or not, however it knows that someone will define that in some other layer (`TemplateView.get`) that will be responsible for handling the incoming request.

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

class TemplateResponseMixin(object):
    template_name = None

    def render_to_response(self, request, context, **response_kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

`TemplateResponseMixin` alone doesn't give us any clue in regard to its real purpose and `render_to_response` itself makes no sense at all. However, together with the `view`, it will be used for rendering a template page using view's logic (in other words *skeleton*).

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'some_app/some_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = get_context_from_somewhere(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(request, context)
```

There is a very educational `SO` thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) about mixins. I'd recommend you to read all answers very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You don't inject something **into** mixin.  Purpose of mixins is the opposite - you should inject properties/methods into your class **from** mixin.

So when your view class mix in the [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin) you will get `template_name`, `render_to_response()` etc in the view.