# Is Mixin a special case of Policy-Based Design?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, policy-based-design, template-mixins

As far as I know, mixin is when you first write the derived class, and then you can inject the base class to it through a template parameter.

Example: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445

As I know Policy-based design is meant for the same.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

It doesn't say you should derive from it, you can use the template parameter other ways also. However, for example in Wikipedia Policy-based design example is something like this:

```
template<typename Base>
class Derive: private Base
```

Which is I think the same as mixin. (instead, that in mixins you usually use public inheritence)

Is there any significant difference between them or mixin is a special case of Policy-based design?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/533675/1147772

Comment: This is not related to my question. By the way as i know mixin mean a different thing in C++ than in any other language.

Comment: A mixin is a principle, the way you implement it (multiple inheritance, template or not etc.) is just that, a way to implement it, as long as you get what you expect i don't think there is a "right" design for it, whether it is policy based or not :)