# How do I prevent Django from running unit tests on parent class when subclassing TestCase?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

**Background:** I am working on a web scraper to track prices at online stores. It uses Django. I have a module for each store, with functions like `get_price()` and `get_product_name()` written for each one, so that the modules can be used interchangeably by the main scraper module. I have store_a.py, store_b.py, store_c.py, et cetera, each with these functions defined.

In order to prevent duplication of code, I've made StoreTestCase, which inherits from TestCase. For each store, I have a subclass of StoreTestCase, like StoreATestCase and StoreBTestCase.

When I manually test the StoreATestCase *class*, the test runner does what I want. It uses the data in the child class `self.data` for its tests, and doesn't attempt to set up and test the parent class on its own:

```
python manage.py test myproject.tests.test_store_a.StoreATest
```

However, when I manually test against the *module*, like:

```
python manage.py test myproject.tests.test_store_a
```

It first runs the tests for the child class and succeeds, but then it runs them for the parent class and returns the following error:

```
    for page in self.data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**store_test.py** (parent class)

```
from django.test import TestCase

class StoreTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        '''This should never execute but it does when I test test_store_a'''
        self.data = None
    def test_get_price(self):
        for page in self.data:
            self.assertEqual(store_a.get_price(page['url']), page['expected_price'])
```

**test_store_a.py** (child class)

```
import store_a
from store_test import StoreTestCase

class StoreATestCase(StoreTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data = [{'url': 'http://www.foo.com/bar', 'expected_price': 7.99},
                     {'url': 'http://www.foo.com/baz', 'expected_price': 12.67}]
```

How do I ensure the Django test runner only tests the child class, and not the parent class?

Comment: if you don't call `super` or the `StoreTestCase.__init__` directly, it should never execute it since it's been overridden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to fix this is to use [`Mixins`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful):

```
from django.test import TestCase

class StoreTestCase(object):

    def setUp(self):
        '''This should never execute but it does when I test test_store_a'''
        self.data = None
    def test_get_price(self):
        for page in self.data:
            self.assertEqual(store_a.get_price(page['url']), page['expected_price'])

class StoreATestCase(StoreTestCase, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data = [{'url': 'http://www.foo.com/bar', 'expected_price': 7.99},
                     {'url': 'http://www.foo.com/baz', 'expected_price': 12.67}]
```

The `StoreTestCase` will not be executed since it is not a `TestCase`, but your `StoreATestCase` will still benefit from the inheritance.

I think that your issue happens because `StoreTestCase` is a `TestCase` instance, so it gets executed when you run the tests.

Edit:

I would also suggest to raise an exception in `StoreTestCase.setUp`, explicitly saying that is not implemented. Have a look at [these exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError).
You would end up with something like this:

```
import exceptions  # At the top of the file

[...]

def setUp(object):
    raise exceptions.NotImplementedError('Please override this method in your subclass')
```

Comment: Isn't it invalid to do self.assertEqual() on StoreTestCase(object) since it doesn't have that method?

Comment: It is perfectly valid, it will use the `assertEqual` from `StoreATestCase`. Have a look at the link in the answer (Mixins).

Answer (score 5):

You can to hide base class inside another:

**store_test.py** (parent class)

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestHelpers(object):
    class StoreTestCase(TestCase):
    ...
```

**test_store_a.py** (child class)

```
import store_a
from store_test import TestHelpers

class StoreATestCase(TestHelpers.StoreTestCase):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the Multi-inheritance, this is a possible solution as well. Django Test Cases are not called via the **init** constructor so the setUp Method has to be overridden:

```
from unittest import SkipTest
from django.test import TestCase

class BaseTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        if self.__class__ == BaseTest:
            raise SkipTest('Abstract test')
        your_stuff = 'here'
...
```

The only downside is, that the skipped test will be mentioned in your test report.
Unittest documentation:
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.SkipTest