# Is it possible to implement .NET-like attributes in Python?

Tags: c#, .net, python-3.x, argparse, python-decorators

I'm a big fan of .NETs attributes - pre-defined and user-defined ones. Attributes are classes inherited from `Attribute`. Mostly everything in .NET (classes, methods, members (properties, fields, enum values)) can be 'decorated'/equipped with attributes. This attributes can be read-back by e.g. the compiler to extract compiler hints or by the user as kind of meta programming.

C# example:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class SampleClass {
  // Objects of this type can be serialized.
}
```

VB example:

```vb
<System.Serializable()>
Public Class SampleClass
  ' Objects of this type can be serialized.
End Class
```

In my example `Serializable` marks a class for serialization. A serializer can now retrieve all members of that class' instances and assemble the instance data to a serialized object. It's also possible so mark single fields to be serialized or not.

A user can get defined attributes from a class with the help of reflection: `System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(...)`

For further reading (MSDN documentation):
 - [Writing Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx)
 - [Retrieving Information Stored in Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm also a big fan of Python and decorators. Is it possible to implement .NET-like attributes in Python with the help of decorators? What would it look like in Python?

```py
@Serializable
class SampleClass():
  # Objects of this type can be serialized.
```

Another use case could be the Python `argparse` library. It's possible to register callback functions, which are called by sub-parsers if the input contains the correct sub-command. A more natural way to define such command line argument syntax could be the usage of decorators.

**This question is not about serialization - it's just an usage example.**

Comment: If you expect an answer from the python community you may want to explain what ".NET attributes" are and what your C# and VB snippets do.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to decorate a class, but a more Pythonic approach would be to define a `Serializable` [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) and implement the appropriate methods in classes inheriting it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I extended my question with a short explanation. I hope I could explain the main intention of attributes in .NET. I'll add further links to the original documentation for further reading and an hopefully good example. (It's to big and of topic to the question to post it here :) )

Comment: @jonrsharpe The question is not about serialization, it's about implementation of .NET -like attributes. The serialization is just an example for good attribute usage.

Comment: I didn't roll anything back - I rearranged the extra information you'd added to be inline, rather than tacked on at the end, and removed the link to a separate question that is only tangentially relevant. If this isn't about serialization, could you explain a little more about what an *"attribute"* actually does? What does *"marks a class"* mean? And note that defining ABCs isn't limited to serialization, either...

Comment: @jonrsharpe A sorry, I didn't notice that you moved some parts of my edit into the first paragraph.

Comment: It seems like mixins might be the right answer for this. Have you look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)?

Comment: @ashes999 Please see my updated self-answer below. I implemented a solution with decorators and mixins to ease the usage. An running example was uploaded to github (see the link at the end of my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played a bit with class-based decorators and <del>as far as</del> I can tell it's possible to implement .NET-like attributes in Python.

**So first let's develop a meaningful use case:**
Most of us know the Python `argparse` command line argument parser. This parser can handle sub-commands like `git commit -m "message"` where *commit* is a sub-command and `-m <message>` is a parameter of this sub-command parser. It's possible to assign a callback function to each sub-command parser.

> **Python 3.4.2 for Windows** has a bug in handling callback functions. It's fixed in 3.5.0 (I haven't tested other 3.4.x versions).

Here is a classic `argparse` example:

```py
class MyProg():

  def Run(self):
    # create a commandline argument parser
    MainParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description = textwrap.dedent('''This is the User Service Tool.'''),
      formatter_class = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      add_help=False)

    MainParser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest="verbose", help='print out detailed messages', action='store_const', const=True, default=False)
    MainParser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', dest="debug", help='enable debug mode', action='store_const', const=True, default=False)
    MainParser.set_defaults(func=self.HandleDefault)
    subParsers = MainParser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

    # UserManagement commads
    # create the sub-parser for the "create-user" command
    CreateUserParser = subParsers.add_parser('create-user', help='create-user help')
    CreateUserParser.add_argument(metavar='<Username>', dest="Users", type=str, nargs='+', help='todo help')
    CreateUserParser.set_defaults(func=self.HandleCreateUser)

    # create the sub-parser for the "remove-user" command
    RemoveUserParser = subParsers.add_parser('remove-user', help='remove-user help')
    RemoveUserParser.add_argument(metavar='<UserID>', dest="UserIDs", type=str, nargs='+', help='todo help')
    RemoveUserParser.set_defaults(func=self.HandleRemoveUser)

  def HandleDefault(self, args):
    print("HandleDefault:")

  def HandleCreateUser(self, args):
    print("HandleCreateUser: {0}".format(str(args.Users)))

  def HandleRemoveUser(self, args):
    print("HandleRemoveUser: {0}".format(str(args.UserIDs)))


my = MyProg()
my.Run()
```

A better and more descriptive solution could look like this:

```py
class MyProg():
  def __init__(self):
    self.BuildParser()
    # ...
  def BuiltParser(self):
    # 1. search self for methods (potential handlers)
    # 2. search this methods for attributes
    # 3. extract Command and Argument attributes
    # 4. create the parser with that provided metadata

  # UserManagement commads
  @CommandAttribute('create-user', help="create-user help")
  @ArgumentAttribute(metavar='<Username>', dest="Users", type=str, nargs='+', help='todo help')
  def HandleCreateUser(self, args):
    print("HandleCreateUser: {0}".format(str(args.Users)))

  @CommandAttribute('remove-user',help="remove-user help")
  @ArgumentAttribute(metavar='<UserID>', dest="UserIDs", type=str, nargs='+', help='todo help')
  def HandleRemoveUser(self, args):
    print("HandleRemoveUser: {0}".format(str(args.UserIDs)))
```

---

**Step 1 - A common `Attribute` class**

So let's develop a common `Attribute` class, which is also a class-based decorator. This decorator adds himself to a list called `__attributes__`, which is registered on the function which is to be decorated.

```py
class Attribute():
  AttributesMemberName =  "__attributes__"
  _debug =                False

  def __call__(self, func):
    # inherit attributes and append myself or create a new attributes list
    if (func.__dict__.__contains__(Attribute.AttributesMemberName)):
      func.__dict__[Attribute.AttributesMemberName].append(self)
    else:
      func.__setattr__(Attribute.AttributesMemberName, [self])
    return func

  def __str__(self):
    return self.__name__

  @classmethod
  def GetAttributes(self, method):
    if method.__dict__.__contains__(Attribute.AttributesMemberName):
      attributes = method.__dict__[Attribute.AttributesMemberName]
      if isinstance(attributes, list):
        return [attribute for attribute in attributes if isinstance(attribute, self)]
    return list()
```

**Step 2 - User defined attributes**

Now we can create custom attributes which inherit the basic decorative functionality from `Attribute`. I'll declare 3 attributes:

- **DefaultAttribute** - If no sub-command parser recognizes a command, this decorated method will be the fallback handler.
- **CommandAttribute** - Define a sub-command and register the decorated function as a callback.
- **ArgumentAttribute** - Add parameters to the sub-command parser.

```py
class DefaultAttribute(Attribute):
  __handler = None

  def __call__(self, func):
    self.__handler = func
    return super().__call__(func)

  @property
  def Handler(self):
    return self.__handler

class CommandAttribute(Attribute):
  __command = ""
  __handler = None
  __kwargs =  None

  def __init__(self, command, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.__command =  command
    self.__kwargs =   kwargs

  def __call__(self, func):
    self.__handler = func
    return super().__call__(func)

  @property
  def Command(self):
    return self.__command

  @property
  def Handler(self):
    return self.__handler

  @property
  def KWArgs(self):
    return self.__kwargs

class ArgumentAttribute(Attribute):
  __args =   None
  __kwargs = None

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.__args =   args
    self.__kwargs = kwargs

  @property
  def Args(self):
    return self.__args

  @property
  def KWArgs(self):
    return self.__kwargs
```

**Step 3 - Building a helper mixin class to handle attributes on methods**

To ease the work with attributes I implemented a `AttributeHelperMixin` class, that can:

- retrieve all methods of a class
- check if a method has attributes and
- return a list of attributes on a given method.

```py
class AttributeHelperMixin():
  def GetMethods(self):
    return {funcname: func
            for funcname, func in self.__class__.__dict__.items()
            if hasattr(func, '__dict__')
           }.items()

  def HasAttribute(self, method):
    if method.__dict__.__contains__(Attribute.AttributesMemberName):
      attributeList = method.__dict__[Attribute.AttributesMemberName]
      return (isinstance(attributeList, list) and (len(attributeList) != 0))
    else:
      return False

  def GetAttributes(self, method):
    if method.__dict__.__contains__(Attribute.AttributesMemberName):
      attributeList = method.__dict__[Attribute.AttributesMemberName]
      if isinstance(attributeList, list):
        return attributeList
    return list()
```

**Step 4 - Build an application class**

Now it's time to build an application class that inherits from `MyBase` and from `ArgParseMixin`. I'll discuss `ArgParseMixin` later. The class has a normal constructor, which calls both base-class constructors. It also adds 2 arguments for *verbose* and *debug* to the main-parser. All callback handlers are decorated with the new Attributes.

```py
class MyBase():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class prog(MyBase, ArgParseMixin):
  def __init__(self):
    import argparse
    import textwrap

    # call constructor of the main interitance tree
    MyBase.__init__(self)

    # Call the constructor of the ArgParseMixin
    ArgParseMixin.__init__(self,
      description = textwrap.dedent('''\
        This is the Admin Service Tool.
        '''),
      formatter_class = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      add_help=False)

    self.MainParser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',  dest="verbose",  help='print out detailed messages',  action='store_const', const=True, default=False)
    self.MainParser.add_argument('-d', '--debug',    dest="debug",    help='enable debug mode',            action='store_const', const=True, default=False)

  def Run(self):
    ArgParseMixin.Run(self)

  @DefaultAttribute()
  def HandleDefault(self, args):
    print("DefaultHandler: verbose={0}  debug={1}".format(str(args.verbose), str(args.debug)))

  @CommandAttribute("create-user", help="my new command")
  @ArgumentAttribute(metavar='<Username>', dest="Users", type=str, help='todo help')
  def HandleCreateUser(self, args):
    print("HandleCreateUser: {0}".format(str(args.Users)))

  @CommandAttribute("remove-user", help="my new command")
  @ArgumentAttribute(metavar='<UserID>', dest="UserIDs", type=str, help='todo help')
  def HandleRemoveUser(self, args):
    print("HandleRemoveUser: {0}".format(str(args.UserIDs)))

p = prog()
p.Run()
```

**Step 5 - The `ArgParseMixin` helper class.**

This class constructs the `argparse` based parser with the provided data from attributes. The parsing process is invoked by `Run()`.

```py
class ArgParseMixin(AttributeHelperMixin):
  __mainParser = None
  __subParser =  None
  __subParsers = {}

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

    # create a commandline argument parser
    import argparse
    self.__mainParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(**kwargs)
    self.__subParser =  self.__mainParser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

    for funcname,func in self.GetMethods():
      defAttributes = DefaultAttribute.GetAttributes(func)
      if (len(defAttributes) != 0):
        defAttribute = defAttributes[0]
        self.__mainParser.set_defaults(func=defAttribute.Handler)
        continue

      cmdAttributes = CommandAttribute.GetAttributes(func)
      if (len(cmdAttributes) != 0):
        cmdAttribute = cmdAttributes[0]
        subParser = self.__subParser.add_parser(cmdAttribute.Command, **(cmdAttribute.KWArgs))
        subParser.set_defaults(func=cmdAttribute.Handler)

        for argAttribute in ArgumentAttribute.GetAttributes(func):
          subParser.add_argument(*(argAttribute.Args), **(argAttribute.KWArgs))

        self.__subParsers[cmdAttribute.Command] = subParser
        continue

  def Run(self):
    # parse command line options and process splitted arguments in callback functions
    args = self.__mainParser.parse_args()
    # because func is a function (unbound to an object), it MUST be called with self as a first parameter
    args.func(self, args)

  @property
  def MainParser(self):
    return self.__mainParser

  @property
  def SubParsers(self):
    return self.__subParsers
```

---

I'll provide my code and examples on GitHub as [pyAttribute](https://github.com/Paebbels/pyAttribute) repository.

Comment: Nice example but it would be better if it was written in a more pythonic style:
- DONT name this "Attributes" - in python, "attribute" has a well defined and totally different meaning
- attributes (python meaning) names should be in all_lower
- use generic functions not implementation `__magic_methods__` ie `setattr(obj, name, attr)`, not `obj.__setattr__(name, attr)`, and avoid accessing `obj.__dict__`  directly unless you have a compelling reason to do so

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac is an `argparse` front end.  It can create subparsers by decorating a function.  The subparser's arguments are the function's arguments.  It can also use Python3 `function annotations`.  I started with `plac` several years ago, but now find it more natural to work with `argparse` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Given this `Serializable` attribute, you probably want to have a simple solution.

```
class C:
    b = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def f(self):
        pass


>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{'a': 1}
```

80% of work is already done in `__dict__` magic attribute that is available for every object. You probably want to have a class-level list of serializable members and make use of `__getattribute__` magic methid for modifying what your `__dict__` attribute will return for your class.

The same applies to the rest of C# attributes you want to port. I don't think there's a general way to port a random attribute to decorator syntax without writing a ton of code. So for the sake of simplicity, my suggestion is not to stick to decorators and look for short and simple ways.

Comment: The question is not about serialization - it's just an example where .NET uses attributes. Another one would be the [`FlagAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to mark enumerations as bit-fields (one-hot encoding) otherwise all members would have increasing integer values.

Comment: Not all objects have a `__dict__`, and not all attributes of an object are stored in it's `__dict__`.

Comment: @Paebbels the answer is not about serialization too. It's about my opinion not to stick to decorators. It is possible, but not advised.

Comment: @bruno yes, this is true. That's why I said "80%", not "100%" :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I updated my own answer: It's possible to implement .NET like attributes with the help of Python decorators. I also posted a hopefully good usecase on how to use such metadata objects. As in the .NET implementation, `Attribute` is a class, the syntax is similar and the usage feels also mostly the same :)