# What do multiple parameters of class MyModel(..., models.Model) beside models.Model in Django mean?

Tags: django

```
class Post(AnoterModelMixin, AANotherModelMixin, models.Model):
```

What does this mean if it's in `models.py` for django?

Comment: multiple inheritance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically, it's a really convenient way of organizing your code. [A mixin is a special kind of multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/258755).

`AnoterModelMixin` can contain a set of methods that you can use on your model; these are inherited:

```
class Post(AnoterModelMixin, AANotherModelMixin, models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

`AnoterModelMixin` could look like this:

```
class AnoterModelMixin(object):
"""Additional methods on the Post model"""

   def get_short_name(self):
   """Returns the first 10 characters of the post name"""
      return self.name[:10]

   def get_longer_name(self):
   """Returns the first 15 characters of the post name"""
      return self.name[:15]
```

You can then use it like so:

```
demo_post = Post.objects.create(name='This is a very long post name')
demo_post.get_short_name() # 'This is a '
demo_post.get_longer_name() # 'This is a very '
```