# Retrieving arguments from a class with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, introspection

Is it possible to retrieve all arguments from an object, that has multiple parent classes, using `inspect.getargspec()`or any other option?

Example:

```
import inspect

class One:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

class Two:
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b = b

class Three(One, Two):
    pass

print(inspect.getargspec(Three.__init__))
```

Instead:
`ArgSpec(args=['self', 'a'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)` as an output, I am looking for the way to have:
`['self', 'a','b']` for args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
args = ['self']
for C in Three.__mro__:
    if '__init__' in C.__dict__:
        args += inspect.getargspec(C).args[1:]
```

*Edit:*

As a bit of clarification for head scratching people:

`self` is returned for all bound methods when calling `getargspec` so start out with that as a default value. This way we can skip it everywhere (otherwise it would end up in the list multiple times - could also use a `set()` to avoid this).

We run through the class' method resolution order list (`__mro__`).

Under normal circumstances this list is used to determine which function to call, but in the case of initialization it tells the `super().__init__()` calls which one is next (which is why it's important that you always call - even if you don't from inherit anything - it or you'll interrupt the chain)

For every class type we get back, see if it has an `__init__` of its own.

If it does, run the `getargspec` function on it and add the resulting list of argument names to the initial list, skipping `self`.

Note: For python 3+, use `getfullargspec` instead.

Comment: Some explanation will dramatically increase the value of your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read up on [python Mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) first.

In general, it's pretty bad form to use multiple inheritance using two classes with conflicting names.  The class on the far left is always prioritized, leading to some funky things for methods from the other classes that use the overwritten method.

If you want an object with a variable number of args/kwargs, you should just specify that.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```