# tkinter - How to drag and drop widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a Python program in which you can move around widgets.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
main = tk.Tk()
notesFrame = tk.Frame(main, bd = 4, bg = "a6a6a6")
notesFrame.place(x=10,y=10)
notes = tk.Text(notesFrame)
notes.pack()
notesFrame.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: notesFrame.place(x = event.x, y = event.y)
```

But, this gets super glitchy and the widget jumps back and forth.

Comment: Did you actually try *this* code? Cause it has multiple errors, and doesn't appear to move anything - at least under Python 3.5 on Mac.

Comment: You have the click the border, not the text box

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is caused by the fact that the event's coordinates are relative to the dragged widget. Updating the widget's position (in *absolute* coordinates) with *relative* coordinates obviously results in chaos.

To fix this, I've used the [`.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_y()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_x-method) functions (which allow to turn the relative coordinates into absolute ones), and the `Button-1` event to determine the cursor's location on the widget when the drag starts.

Here's a function that makes a widget draggable:

```
def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

def on_drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)
```

It can be used like so:

```
main = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(main, bd=4, bg="grey")
frame.place(x=10, y=10)
make_draggable(frame)

notes = tk.Text(frame)
notes.pack()
```

---

If you want to take a more object-oriented approach, you can write a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) that makes all instances of a class draggable:

```
class DragDropMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        make_draggable(self)
```

Usage:

```
# As always when it comes to mixins, make sure to
# inherit from DragDropMixin FIRST!
class DnDFrame(DragDropMixin, tk.Frame):
    pass

# This wouldn't work:
# class DnDFrame(tk.Frame, DragDropMixin):
#     pass

main = tk.Tk()

frame = DnDFrame(main, bd=4, bg="grey")
frame.place(x=10, y=10)

notes = tk.Text(frame)
notes.pack()
```

Comment: Motion 1: Do nothing, Motion 2: change place. That's a little bug i think.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Aran-Fey. This helped me to drag my main window from a child widget that was a label.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a different approach and it is useful when you want ALL of your widgets drag-able in the SAME window. I do also like the math used in this approach more than in the accepted answer.

The code is explained line by line as commented lines below:

```
import tkinter as tk

def drag_widget(event):
    if (w:=root.dragged_widget): #walrus assignment
        cx,cy = w.winfo_x(), w.winfo_y() #current x and y
        #deltaX and deltaY to mouse position stored
        dx = root.marked_pointx - root.winfo_pointerx()
        dy = root.marked_pointy - root.winfo_pointery()
        #adjust widget by deltaX and deltaY
        w.place(x=cx-dx, y=cy-dy)
        #update the marked for next iteration
        root.marked_pointx = root.winfo_pointerx()
        root.marked_pointy = root.winfo_pointery()

def drag_init(event):
    if event.widget is not root:
        #store the widget that is clicked
        root.dragged_widget = event.widget
        #ensure dragged widget is ontop
        event.widget.lift()
        #store the currently mouse position
        root.marked_pointx = root.winfo_pointerx()
        root.marked_pointy = root.winfo_pointery()

def finalize_dragging(event):
    #default setup
    root.dragged_widget = None
    
root = tk.Tk()
#name and register some events to some sequences
root.event_add('<<Drag>>', '<B1-Motion>')
root.event_add('<<DragInit>>', '<ButtonPress-1>')
root.event_add('<<DragFinal>>', '<ButtonRelease-1>')
#bind named events to the functions that shall be executed
root.bind('<<DragInit>>', drag_init)
root.bind('<<Drag>>', drag_widget)
root.bind('<<DragFinal>>', finalize_dragging)
#fire the finalizer of dragging for setup
root.event_generate('<<DragFinal>>')
#populate the window
for color in ['yellow','red','green','orange']:
    tk.Label(root, text="test",bg=color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter has a module for this, documented in the module docstring.  It was expected that it would  be replaced by a tk dnd module, but this has not happened.  I have never tried it.  Searching SO for `[tkinter] dnd` returns [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[tkinter]%20dnd).  Below is the beginning of the docstring.

```
>>> from tkinter import dnd
>>> help(dnd)
Help on module tkinter.dnd in tkinter:

NAME
    tkinter.dnd - Drag-and-drop support for Tkinter.

DESCRIPTION
    This is very preliminary.  I currently only support dnd *within* one
    application, between different windows (or within the same window).
[snip]
```

Comment: The entire docstring can be viewed in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py).