# Tkinter: Registering two left clicks?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is click twice on the canvas and get the `event.x` and `event.y` for both the mouse clicks so I can use it draw primitives.

I would like to use the two sets of event values to calculate the distance and use it as a radius to draw circle.

At the moment I am able to get it only for a single click.

```
def leftClick(event=None):
    print("left",event.x,event.y)

c.bind("<Button-1>",leftClick)
```

Comment: Your event handler will need to have a "state" so it know whether the click is the first or second. If you make it part of a class, it can store the first click's coordinates as `self` attributes.

Comment: Instead of two isolated mouse clicks, it might be better to make the user move the mouse with the button down between the two positions called "drag and drop" — you could even draw temporary circles shoing the current size defined while this is happening. Tkinter doesn't have any direct support for this, so see [How make Drag and Drop interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887576/how-make-drag-and-drop-interface) for some ideas on how to implement it.

Comment: This sounds good, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding it with

```
c.bind('<Double-Button-1>', function)
```

And define the function as per your requirements

Comment: How is binding to this evnt going to provide two sets of event x and y values?